# Опрос: Отношение сообщества к вопросам, затрагивающим этику, правонарушения и интересы третьих лиц

Tags: обсуждение, правила, опрос

Этот опрос призван выработать позицию нашего русскоязычного сообщества *StackOverflow на русском* по вопросам, связанным с нарушениями этических и юридических норм.

Речь **не идет о тех случаях**, когда текст вопроса непосредственно нарушает условия использования SO или законы (ссылки на варез, оскорбления, непристойное содержание), с этим все понятно.

Я же предлагаю рассмотреть "скользкие" вопросы, ответы на которые участник может или планирует использовать со злым умыслом, для нарушения законов или прав третьих лиц.

Примеры вопросов:

- разработка вирусов, эксплоитов, бэкдоров, спамботов, взлом

  - [Взлом сайтов: литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/118828)
  - [Получение доступа(взлом) к роутеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480476)
  - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469028
- автоматическое распознавание или обход капчи

  - [Как распознают капчи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/67204)
  - [Получение капчи с сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/60322)
- автоматический парсинг ресурса Интернет, который явно оговаривает запрет на это

  - [Торговая площадка steam](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511283)
  - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513746
- обход защиты/ограничений на использование какого-либо продукта

  - [Защита от скачивания картинок с сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359478)

> На META.SE не раз всплывало подобное обсуждение, и каждый раз сообщество склонялось к разрешению подобных тем:
>
> - [Policy regarding questions related to unethical or "shady" practices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80495)
> - [How far should we go in judging question ethics?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25286)
> - [Web Scraping, Intellectual Property and the Ethics of Answering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93698)
> - [New close reason: "questionable ethics"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195711)

Аргументы **ЗА**:

- Нужно разделять техническую и этическую сторону вопроса: этика у кажого своя, а мы делимся техническими решениями и знаниями.И вообще, вправе ли мы осуждать?
- Никого насильно не обязывают отвечать на такие вопросы.
- Автор вопроса сам отвечает за свои последующие поступки.
- Лучше иметь открытую информацию об уязвимостях, чтобы понимать как защититься.
- Главное, чтобы вопрос удовлетворял требованиям качества и правилам, в том числе не был оффтопиком.

Аргументы **ПРОТИВ**

- Мы помогаем расширить круг лиц, которые могут заниматься сомнительной деятельностью: если раньше им не хватало технических навыков, теперь им будет проще.
- Мы не эксперты по законам, чтобы давать автору взвешенную юридическую оценку последствиям.
- Информация из ответов может доставить автору вопроса неприятности (потенциально крупные), связанные с законом: на дисклеймер он с высокой вероятностью забьёт, ведь ему "очень надо".
- Часто автор вопроса не в курсе, для чего существуют те или иные ограничения, кого они защищают и по кому ударит их обход.

Comment: я думаю стоит перенести пункт про автор не в курсе в плюс - так как если в ответе ему расскажут кроме прочего _почему_ эти ограничения возможно это так же повлияет на дальнейшие действия автора

Comment: Замечу, что вопрос "Как обойти ограничения VK API?", несмотря на  настораживающее название, сводится к тому, как запросить у сервера 2-ю, 3-ю, и т. д. страницы результатов. Не хотелось бы, чтобы вопросы удалялись в результате поверхностого осмотра.

Comment: @Marshmallow, вопрос с двояким толкованием, и спасает его ответ, но я заменил на более явный случай, чтобы никого не смущать.

Comment: А можно к вопросам о рассылке спама автоматически подвёрстывать настоящий e-mail автора?

Comment: Пособник - это лицо, содействовавшее совершению преступления **советами**, указаниями, предоставлением средств или устранением препятствий, а также лицо, заранее обещавшее скрыть преступника, орудия и средства совершения преступления, следы преступления либо предметы, добытые преступным путем, а равно лицо, заранее обещавшее приобрести или сбыть такие предметы.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1070/178988

Comment: Нет аргумента «против», что у Stack Overflow могут возникнуть неприятности с властями и правоохранительными органами.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, это вряд ли. Максимум попросят удалить какой-то контент. EN.SO уже много лет и серьезных проблем, видимо, не было, раз мы тут общаемся. К тому же у SO есть штат юристов.

Comment: @Nofate при желании, SO может подать в суд на почти любую контору, найти у них в исходниках копипасту из ответов без attribution, и закрыть ее с концами.

Comment: @PashaPash, вот так ловко они посадили весь мир на крючок )

Comment: @Nofate, всё же то западные, а на RU SO приходится учитывать и российские реалии, когда всерьёз рассуждают о [«великом фаерволе»](https://geektimes.ru/post/274622/).

Comment: @Nofate будь я из РФ, я бы заподозрил в этом сионистский заговор. Кстати, кто главный в SO? Wait... oh s..! :))

Comment: *"Мы не эксперты по законам, чтобы давать автору взвешенную юридическую оценку последствиям."* - в моем понимании, это аргумент "за", а не "против"

Comment: Этика, мораль - понятия относительные. Вчера всё было правильно, сегодня другие времена и все обязаны любить представителей сексуальных меньшинств и не противляться, если они тебя полюбят. Завтра победит ислам - всем неверным надо будет отрезать головы. И это будет этично и сверх-морально.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Подобные вопросы допустимы. Не нужно их закрывать/удалять.

Comment: Пособником признается лицо, содействовавшее совершению __преступления__. С каких пор получение знаний это преступление? Может я хочу детально ознакомится со способами взлома капчи, чтобы обезопасить свой сайт и т.д.
Кроме того - [презумция невиновности](http://www.zakonrf.info/upk/14/)

Comment: @jumpjet67, полагаю, Cerbo и edem говорят о ситуации, когда ТС воспользовался ответом с RU.SO для совершения преступления.

Comment: @edem, кстати, зря убрали "возможно". Это было рассуждение, а не призыв к действию.

Comment: слишком широкая трактовка закона, смотрите комментарии, и в частности решение судебной коллегии по уголовным делам ВС РФ указавшей, что при пособничестве лицо __осознает__, что оно способствует исполнителю в совершении конкретного преступления, предвидит, что преступный результат является для них общим, и желает или сознательно допускает его наступление

Comment: в данном конкретном случае идёт речь о свободном обмене знаниями во-первых - напрямую с преступлениями никак не связанными, а во-вторых - общедоступными.

Comment: @jumpjet67 Мой коментарий о том, что в вопросе приводятся аргументы ЗА в том ключе, что: мы свободно распространяем знания, а как их будет использовать ТС не наше дело. Так вот УК не совсем с этим согласен, так как если отвечающий осознает, что готовится преступление, то он становится пособником. Следовательно это противоречит условиям использования СО.

Comment: Коллеги, следуя такой логике инструктор автошколы является соучастником угонщика (если угонщик когда-то учился там). Бред.

Comment: @edem, там их учат водить. А не умея водить, невозможно угнать. Просто сложите 2 + 2

Comment: @edem, вот именно. Так что, Ваши страхи абсолютно напрасны. Поверьте, что если дело дойдет до допросов (как Вы в чате писали), то либо Вы сами признаетесь во всем, что следак будет клеить, либо у Вас в кармане (конечно же, при понятых и с соблюдением всех процессуальных  норм) обнаружат пару патронов и пакетик с белым порошком и "... казенный дом, дорога дальняя..." В любом случае у нас всегда справедлива поговорка -- "был бы человек, а статья найдется". Так что, не волнуйтесь, от судьбы не уйдешь (хотя, не стоит забывать, что "береженого Бог бережет, а не береженого конвой стережет".

Comment: @edem именно, "пособником признается лицо, содействовавшее __совершению преступления__". То есть если ТС задаёт вопрос "я собираюсь взломать капчу и найти эксплоит в API вк, чтобы угнать аккаунты юзеров" - становится ясно, что готовится преступление. С этого момента любые советы типа "Лучше всего взломать капчу вк можно так, так и так, я сто раз пробовал" - будут считаться пособничеством. Всё остальное это домыслы, догадки и истерия на почве УК РФ. Как правильно заметил avp - "был бы человек, а статья найдется", так что отставить панику.

Comment: @jumpjet67, edem добавлю. Читал сегодня утром правоприменительную практику и бюллетени Верховного Суда ВФ. Пособничество предполагает наличие "умысла". То есть отвечающий должен хотеть способствовать совершению преступления, быть заинтересованным в этом.

Comment: @edem, прежде всего, **информация должна быть свободной**, а все остальное -- как описанные Вами действия называть, зависит от ситуации.

Comment: @edem я из Беларуси, сижу на сайте американской компании. Причем тут УК РФ?

Comment: @edem что помешает россиянину просто проигнорировать УК РБ? и опять же - в вопросе приведены конкретные проблемные темы. К каким из сомнительных вопросов применим УК РФ? Особенно если учитывать, что т.н. "запрет на парсинг" в правилах любого сайта юридически ничтожен, и хоть какому-то наказанию подлежит только несанцкионированный доступ к информации, сопровождавшийся  нарушением системы защиты.

Comment: @edem я к тому, что любая отсылка к УК РФ в теле ответа,  и любые предупреждения о возможных наказаниях - это **не имеющий никакого смысла шум**, который подлежит вырезанию.

Comment: @PashaPash согласен. Тем не менее напоминание про УК в тексте данного ответа убирать не стоит.

Comment: @KromStern упоминание УК было дописано когда вопрос набрал уже (+13, у учетом смены моего голоса +15). Не стоит дописывать неоднозначную правку в вариант, котрый уже набрал популярность. Хотите вариант с УК РФ - запостите его отдельным ответом. И, пожалуйста, воздержитесь от правок без обсуждения их в комментариях.

Comment: @PashaPash тогда ок

Answer (score 23):

## TL;DR

Давайте не будем вырабатывать позицию, а просто будем рассматривать каждый опрос отдельно.

## Альтернативный вариант

По подобным вопросам нельзя выработать общую позицию, и вот почему:

Предположим (на самом деле так и есть), что я - ведущий разработчик на SaaS системе управления проектами. Эдакий MS Project для несофтварных организаций. Как ни странно, это делает меня прямо заинтересованным в:

- Массовой рассылке почты
- Парсинге HTML
- Знании о подходах к взломам сайтов
- Знании о проблемах с устойчивостью капчти
- Знании о том, как обойти защиту API

Тривиальные вопросы - как отладить исключение - никто из моей команды на SO не понесет - по вполне очевидным причинам - уровень не тот, минимальный пример выделить нельзя, проще подойти и дернуть меня, в конце концов.

Что из списка выше я бы спросил на SO (не будь у меня уже готовых решений)

- Массовая рассылка почты без попадания в спам. 100% белый и легитимный вопрос. Почти во всех крупных конторах процесс построен на email. Наша система отправляет около 30000 писем *в день*. С баунсом 0.5% (криво вбитые адреса) и 5(!) жалобами на спам за 3 года (от индусов. кто-то случайно кнопку нажал). Вопрос как не попасть в спам - абсолютно белый и актуальный. Настройка DNS (SFP, DKIM), работа с сервисами вроде SES - это очень актуальный для меня вопрос. Поэтому закрытие вопроса [Массовая рассылка писем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469028), и, тем более, попадание его в список "сомнительных" вызывает у меня недоумение.
- Парсинг HTML - это кажется глупым и забавным, пока не приходит заказчик, у которого надо парсить письма (а у него весь процесс построен на письмах). А письма - в HTML.
- Знание о подходах в к взломам сайтов - меня вот подвело незнание о `X-Frame-Options`. Вот прямо сейчас сижу и пишу *письмо* "починим, почти починили!", одновременно думая, не зацепит ли это скрипты, лежащие на другом домене.
- Устойчивость каптчи и прочие методы защиты от ботов - эти вопросы возникают у разработчика любого сайта с открытой регистрацией. Защита от ботов - актуальна как никогда. Способы ее обхода - тоже.
- Знание об обходе защиты API - я один из тех людей, кто эту защиту строит. Да, я злодей, бросающий 429-ю ошибку. Вводящий paging. Но всегда стоит видеть обратную сторону проблемы - каждый вопрос по обходу защиты - это потенциально новые знания для меня.

---

## Текущая ситуация с точки зрения правил

*Сомнительность* вопроса не может служить причиной закрытия. Тем более не может служить причиной закрытия какое-то мнимое несоответствие УК РФ (я не из РФ, SO - не из РФ, у нас тут свои законы).

Но стоит учесть, что многие из подобных вопросов плохи *сами по себе*, и вполне попадают под другие причины закрытия.

Например, большинство проблем парсинга сайта не являются *техническими* проблемами. У многих сайтов есть API, про существование которого [разработчик парсера просто не догадался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515202/). У многих сайтов без публичного API есть мобильные версии и непубличное API. Некоторые сайты предоставляют API на платной основе. С некоторыми сайтами можно просто *договориться* в частном порядке.

---

## Совсем личное мнение

Нежелание отжалеть 20$ в месяц на оплату нормального API, попытки свалить работу, за которую топикастеру *заплатили* на добровольцев на ruSO - заслуживают минусов и сожжения. Достаточно посмотреть вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485828/, чтобы понять суть проблемы (особенно по метке C#):

> Частенько сталкиваюсь с задачей многопоточного парсинга информации с веб страниц. Поскольку PHP разогнать до достаточного кол-ва потоков с требуемой скоростью обработки весьма проблематично - обычно приходится заказывать парсеры на стороне (на C#). По итогу получается что заказываю десятки однотипных программ.

Если человек взялся (за деньги!) делать работу, на которую у него заведомо не хватает знаний, и пришел на ruSO не за знаниями, а за регуляркой — то минуса заслуживает и он, и тот, кто эту регулярку ему напишет, поощрив тем самым топикастера к созданию новых подобных вопросов.

Вы считаете, что делать 99% работы за тех, кому эти парсеры **заказали** — это достойная трата времени? Я — нет.

Напоминаю, что минусы за вопросы — **бесплатны**.

Comment: Ну, разбор клиентского HTML и веб-скрейпинг — это очень разные задачи. Если клиент _просит_ разобрать его HTML, то он может/должен вместо этого предоставлять (например, прописывать в комментарии, etc.) исходную объектную структуру. Если клиент не хочет сотрудничать, а хочет, чтобы за него из write-only-структуры выудили назад данные, он должен нанять профессионалов и заплатить им соответствующие деньги. Решать такие проблемы бесплатно на StackOverflow по меньшей мере малоэтично.

Comment: А с массовой рассылкой писем обычно проблем не возникает, если слать их с корпоративного сервера. В той же Германии, например, в любом письме из массовой рассылки **обязана** быть прямая, рабочая ссылка на отписку от этой рассылки (иначе за спамера берутся по-серьёзному).

Comment: И да, я за тех, кто бросает 429. (Потому что Lawful.)

Comment: @VladD да, у нас канадцы - и там тоже все строго, вплоть до явного задокументированного получения согласия юзера на отправку почты. и тем не менее - при отправке почты есть базовые вещи, о которых разработчик обычно не догадывается, пока не попытается отправить больше 100 писем - тот же DKIM, например.

Comment: @VladD по поводу парсинга - я обычно просто минусую без комментов (хоть это и нехорошо). проблема в том, что скрейпинг обычно упирается в нетехническую проблему - т.е. никто даже не пытается искать API. Сразу парсят HTML.

Comment: Тогда я предложил бы написать кому-нибудь (вам, раз у вас есть опыт?) канонический вопросоответ о _легальной_ рассылке, и закрывать вопросы о легальной рассылке как дубликаты, а о нелегальной по причине «мы ненавидим тебя, спамер».

Comment: Может сделаем отдельный вопрос для обсуждения этого вопроса? )

Comment: @Nofate: Которого именно? Спам?

Comment: @VladD, *этого* вопроса, `this`. ну тут я пытался сделать голосовалку и надеялся, что дискуссии по ней будут отдельно. Надо было, наверное, сразу завести под обсуждение отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @Nofate а это и есть отдельный пункт - который сводится к "давайте не будем вырабатывать позицию, а просто будем рассматривать каждый вопрос отдельно".

Comment: Угу, возможно, стоит. Потому что у нас пока дискуссия в каментах.

Comment: @VladD, комменты для этого и предназначены... Упс, _не_ выкинул))))

Comment: И вообще, ну ведь все писали парсеры html. Чего ж, сами пишем, а другим помогать нельзя?

Comment: @Nofate, с голосовалкой вроде уже разобрались - вполне себе выделяющиеся +17. при чём за тот же вариант, что и в [прошлый раз](/q/1070/178988).

Comment: @Qwertiy, в прошлый раз была более узкая тема. Сейчас же я пытался не акцентировать внимание на законе, хотя это и не помогло, и все скатилось в битву диванных юристов )

Comment: @Nofate а не надо было дописывать в ответ упоминание УК РФ - оно лично меня раздражает :)

Comment: @PashaPash, так не я дописал. Меня тоже раздражает. Как соевый соус с ГМО.

Comment: @Nofate вырезал. но такая правка ответа с +17 выглядит...сомнительно

Comment: @PashaPash, там было +13 на момент правки

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я никогда не писал парсера HTML на регулярках (или прости господи ручного). Пару раз для примера на SO использовал `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: @VladD, а я [писал](http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6770380#p6770380), причём на разных языках))) Я даже выдирание данных для диаграмм из json'а на регулярках писал - потом оказалось, что при определённом виде диаграмм (месяцы и годы менялись осями) это чудо просто вешало программу - тогда я переписал парсер json'а. В смысле, я _написал_ парсер json'а, который работал линейно. Естественно, всё это было под конкретный вид json'а, в плане, что увидеть всякие пробелы я бы там не хотел, но любой минифицированный json должен был нормально перевариваться.

Comment: @VladD, и распознавание капчи тоже писал. Очень даже хорошо работало, правда, она там несложная была. И программу для скачивания обоев с сайта. И программу для получения ссылки и даже скачивания с файлообменника. И для стима (правда, быстро отказался от использования, а сейчас это вообще неактуально). И ещё кучу всего.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Сразу видно, кто у нас Chaotic :)

Answer (score -1):

Подобные вопросы недопустимы. Их нужно закрывать/удалять.

Answer (score -2):

Подобные вопросы недопустимы, но их можно спасти, если сделать формулировку более абстрактной (не привязывать к конкретному продукту).

Это и применение полученных ответов потребует от автора вопроса определённой технической подкованности и не будет всплывать в результатах поиска по темам вроде "обход ограничений на Х", что сведёт на нет большую часть возможного ущерба от таких ответов.

Answer (score -3):

Считаю, что знания в любом случае - хорошо.

Чем больше будет литературы, тем быстрее будет развиваться эта сравнительно-молодая наука "Информатика". Хакеры придумывают всё более неординарные способы взлома, а мы - способы защиты. Вот что называется эволюцией. Мы становимся умнее.

Но я однозначно за то, чтобы удалять вопросы и ответы, в которых говорится о названиях взламываемых проектов. Они могут навредить карме SO, и не только.