# Запрос на деструктивный код: давать ли ответы?

Tags: обсуждение, возможный-вред

Вопрос проистекает из нашей дискуссии с @VladD в комментариях к вопросу [Можно ли отключить windows defender программно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781095/)
Как необходимо поступать в случае, если ответ на вопрос будет содержать условно деструктивный код?
С одной стороны: далеко не всегда он будет использован во вред, а если и будет, то ТС всегда может найти подобную информацию на иных сайтах.
С другой: многими системными функциями можно безвозвратно повредить систему, и каждый раз предупреждать об этом как-то бессмысленно, что ли...

Comment: Я думаю если запрашивается заранее известно что вопрос для создание хакерской программы или причинения вреда, то я бы удалил вопрос. Если же код сам по себе мирный но может быть где-то в каких-то условиях использован во вред, тогда тут всё законно, а во в ред и молоток можно использовать.

Comment: см. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD/2869#2869

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин важное уточнение: вопрос в этом случае заслуживает закрытия (а потом и, возможно, удаления) не потому что программа хакерская, а потому что создание целой хакерской утилиты это слишком общий вопрос.