# В каком виде обсуждение азартных игр является допустимым?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, спам

Бывают вопросы, в которых мелькают ссылки на какие-либо игорные сайты,

Примеры из последних (некоторые удалены и я уже не могу найти их):

[Игорный сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/910270/213987).

> Кто знает, по какой формуле написана данная игра - <ссылка>? Формула
>   простой рулетки красное, чёрное само собой не подходит. Первый раз
>   сталкиваюсь с такой игрой и формула не понятна.
>
> НЕ РЕКЛАМА!

[Анализ матчей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907564/213987)

> Хочу сделать программу, которая будет анализировть матчи cs:go, но не
>   знаю как java считывает информацию с интернета, все матчи на сайте
>   <ссылка>, программа должна узнать лучшие карты команды, винрейт на них
>   и всю основную инфу. На выводе должен быть победитель и их шансы на
>   победу

[VPN для казино](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906862)

> У нас в Украине заблокировали сайт казино плейфортуна <ссылка> а у меня
>   там приличная сумма денег лежит, хочу скачать впн, чтобы хотя бы
>   вывести деньги, но сколько не нахожу программ, они все платные. может
>   кто знает бесплатную?

Разумеется можно спорить, являются ли эти люди спамерами (некоторые люди стараются разглядеть в людях доброе, даже когда к этому нет особых предпосылок), некоторые напротив.

Давайте всё же обсудим, что делать с подобными вопросами. Жечь калёным железом или сформулировать какие-то критерии, которым должно удовлетворять подобное сообщение/автор, чтобы "остаться в живых"?

Comment: Да был таковой на днях, тоже помнится.

Comment: Немножко связанное: [Опрос: Отношение сообщества к вопросам, затрагивающим этику, правонарушения и интересы третьих лиц](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868)

Comment: *У нас в Украине заблокировали сайт казино плейфортуна <ссылка> а у меня там приличная сумма денег лежит* - пахнет рекламой. если нужен vpn, то почему бы не написать просто *посоветуйте бесплатный vpn*

Answer (score 8):

Только в том случае, если ссылки будут убраны в вид, непригодный для индексации поисковыми машинами.

Человек может искать VPN для порносайта, для казино -- это его личное дело, но если он хочет об этом упомянуть -- то эти подробности можно совершенно спокойно вырезать из вопроса, они совершенно несущественны. Вот [например совершенно не спам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/537695/213987) -- человека не интересует как воткнуть ссылки. То же самое и для сайтов оппозиционных политиков -- VPN'у всё едино, нож как инструмент не является а/моральным (ножом можно резать хлеб или убивать людей) -- всё зависит от того, что за человек его держит и с какими намерениями.

Если вопросы являются существенными и край хочется их обсудить (как пример "не пойму что за алгоритм у этого казино") -- то можно рекомендовать убирать ссылки из поста: желающим открыть первую ревизию не составит труда, а поисковикам нужно запретить просмотр ревизий.

Есть и другие способы сделать ссылку нерабочей, вот два которые мне пришли на ум:

- убирать ссылку в html-комментарий
- заменять в ссылке `http://` на скажем `http://_`

Для спамера ценность представляет собой сама ссылка, нет её -- пожалуйста, можно обсуждать как угодно алгоритмы и прочее.

Если кому-то кажется аморальным взвешивать и судить людей... У нас тут на сайте владельцами устроено пять очередей проверок, в каждой из которых любой желающий с достаточной репутацией имеет право взвесить и оценить вопрос или ответ. Если кому хочется обсуждать -- то давайте обсуждать в объективных терминах.

Comment: Ещё [способ прятать ссылки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314823/339911). Но могут и пофиксить.

Comment: Имхо, вообще не нужны ссылки на сайты в вопросе. Даже когда ссылку дают чтобы мы пошли и посмотрели на код.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ссылки порой очень нужны, если ты трешься в web темах. Вот "поплыл" у меня макет сайта на Bootstrap, как без ссылки спросить в чем проблема? Или спросить как реализованы некоторые вещи на стороннем сайте?

Comment: @Nsk тут вот в чём дело: сайт по ссылке постоянно меняется. Через некоторое время вопрос потеряет смысл, а ответы станут бесполезными. Лично я не хочу тратить время и что-то писать ради одного читателя.

Comment: @Nsk как спрашивать про бутстрап — сделать сниппет, добавить все зависимости в него, чтобы работало. В процессе есть шанс разобраться, понять и ответить на свой вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, мне ссылки в чужих вопросах обычно помогают понять суть вопроса + полезные ссылки встречаются не только на сайта, а еще на мануалы и т.п. А в ифрэйм сниппета не все впихнешь - размер окна/политика cors и так далее.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется постановка вопроса не правильная - вопрос скорее про (ссылочный) спам, не важно какого типа ресурсов (азартных игр/других сайтов). Против ссылочного спама можно на все ссылки вешать rel="nofollow", возможно все ссылки делать через JS/Jquery пытаясь попутно убить referer (не палить владельцам сайтов обсуждения на stackoverflow). Ну и ручная модерация здесь уже есть.

А конкретно про азартные игры - не слышал чтобы написание софта/сайтов для них считалась незаконным, или аморальным.

Comment: Полностью согласен! Ну азартные игры, ну казино, ну покер, ну и что дальше? Это такой же продукт, как какой-нибудь ``https://qiwi.com``, или не дай б-г ``https://vk.com``