# Вопросы про обход ограничений на парсинг сайтов - можно задавать?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, тематика

Наткнулся на вопрос:

[При попытке распарсить html страницу с помощью jsoup включается ограничение доступа, но из браузера она открывается нормально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934768/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-jsoup-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82)

Вкратце, суть такова (с): человек пишет автоматический парсер Кинопоиска.   Кинопоиск как-то определяет, что человек пишет автоматический парсер и сопротивляется. Человек хочет <s>прикинуться шлангом</s> и как-то сделать так, чтобы его робот выглядел человеком. Такие вопросы разрешены? Отвечать на них можно? А если жаловаться, то на оффтоп, как я понимаю?

Comment: А почему их следует не разрешать? Задача "программистская" - "программистская", вопрос задан нормально, правилам SO не противоречит вроде.

Comment: Тут 2 проблемы. Первая, это этическая (и дорожка с подобными вопросами очень скользкая), вторая вроде-бы касается написания кода и должна приносить пользу разработчикам. Надо найти золотую середину.

Comment: Разрешены, [уже обсуждалось](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/213987). Можно задавать, можно отвечать. И поскольку у нас свободная страна -- можно даже минусовать, если кому-то не нравится такой тип вопросов. PS Вопросов таких достаточно много например по метке c# или php.

Comment: Но почему это запрещено? Вроде нигде не написано, что это запрещено.