# Что делать с участниками, которые намеренно публикуют деструктивный код?

Tags: обсуждение, голосование

Первые обсуждения были в этом [вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/%d0%a2%d1%8b-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc?cb=1).

Есть участники, которые публикуют заведомо деструктивный код. Например, многим известную команду `rm -rf /` и её вариации.

Что нужно делать с такими участниками? Публикуйте варианты в ответах.

Comment: Возможно, существует способ проверки кода в тексте вопроса на деструктивность, сравнивая с уже имеющимися примерами, но в любом случае найдется кто-то, кто придет с чем-то новым...

Comment: Мне кажется, обсуждение троллей, публикующими деструктивный код в вопросах, вполне подпадает под собственно обсуждение их деятельности. Если оно, конечно, интересно кому-то :)

Comment: Ничего. Это их право

Comment: Я бы по железу банил их. И буду так делать, если вы выберете меня модератором в этом году!

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Речь вообще-то о вас. "их"???

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич И проблема вообще не в способе бана. А в том что в правилах про такие q/a ничего нет.

Answer (score 0):

Я за то, чтобы ставить тревогу "Спам", а дальше система сама как-то сработает, наверное.

Comment: Причем тут спам, разве это *"Рекламирует продукт или услугу, не раскрывая при этом причастность автора."*? Есть отдельный пункт - **требуется вмешательство модератора**, выбирайте его и пишите в чем дело.

Comment: @Kromster, и дальше что?

Comment: Но это не спам.

Comment: .. и дальше модератор использует свои суперсилы во благо. Инструментами же надо пользоваться по назначению.

Comment: @Kromster, и он ставит тревогу Спам и отклоняет твою.

Comment: С какой стати то спам? ) Вы модератор, вы решайте что делать (банить на время или еще что-то).

Comment: @Kromster, а нет более подходящей тревоги.

Comment: Ну да, не на все случаи жизни по отдельной тревоге заведено, а только на Топ4. Все остальное - объединено в "**требуется вмешательство модератора** - *Проблема не обозначена выше и требует внимания модератора. Пишите конкретно и указывайте детали!*"

Comment: @Kromster, и что модератор должен сделать? Ему доступны только те же тревоги.

Comment: я не знаю что именно вам доступно, но наверняка же у вас есть и баны и удаление постов и прочее прочее?

Comment: @Kromster, удаление постов есть только обычное - просто вместо 5 голосов достаточно 1. Чтобы удалить со скрытием содержимого - только та же тревога Спам. Забанить участника можно, но вроде бы полезный спам автоматически накладывает ограничения на какое-то время, причём ещё и ip банит на сутки.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, так ты согласен или не согласен. Если не согласен, то чего собственный ответ не постишь?

Comment: @Qwertiy я не понимаю, почему вообще обсуждение началось. Тролли по правилам и так баниться должны)

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, и какой вывод?

Comment: @Qwertiy троллей банить надо. Чего тут обсуждать то.