# При попытке перехода из чата на основной профиль выводит ошибку 404

Tags: дефект, поддержка, чат, удалённый-пользователь

Вот [ссылка](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/223633/-says-to-hell-monica) участника в чате. При попытке перехода из чата на [основной профиль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212578/says-to-hell-monica) получаю ошибку `404`.

Это баг?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот участник был удалён в мае. Поэтому и выдаёт ошибку. Это не связанно, в целом, с чатом никак.

По прямой ссылке на профиль в принципе `404` будет отдаваться, т.к. такого профиля больше нет.

Учётка в чате общая по всей сети. После удаления профиля на SOru в профиле чата осталась ссылка. Она автоматически не меняется. Впрочем, и участник может зайти в чат, т.к. профиль чата - это не тоже самое, что профиль на сайте.

Comment: Как участник мог прийти в чат, если он удален?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110556/discussion-between-victor-vosmottor-thanks-monica-and--

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica удалён профиль на SOru. Учётка в чате общая между всеми сайтами SE.

Answer (score 1):

Взял и пришел. Не понимаю что тут странного

Comment: Ладно, извините, меня тут просто пони с ума сводит. Вы в курсе?

Comment: Если человека сводят с ума пони - это не норма

Comment: @РашенБеар https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/%d0%a2%d1%8b-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc?cb=1

Comment: ;D..................