# Вредные ответы, деструктивный код

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

У  нас есть одно вполне эталонное [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10560/213987) "если участник постит вопрос с вредоносным кодом -- что делать?" где договорились, что подобные вопросы -- это неподходящий контент для сайта, закрываем и удаляем.

Тем не менее, есть и вот какая ситуация, когда участник публикует не вопрос, но ответ, содержащий деструктивный код и я вижу, что на этот счёт правил нету.

Давайте с примеров.

Ответ первого рода: даётся некий совет "почистить кеш" командой удаляющей все файлы. Пример (кликабельно):

[image: del “C:" /S /Q /F]

Ответ второго рода: даётся некоторый достаточно логичный совет, после которого опять же идёт совет "если не поможет -- чистим кеш". Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1150123/revisions и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1150860/revisions

Понимаете, какая штука... с одной стороны понятно, что нормальному человеку кажется очевидным набор базовых правил, которые ещё мама-папа должны были привить и если приходится создавать правило для такого очевидно неприемлемого поведения -- то что-то не так. С другой стороны попытка хоть как-то притягивать за уши уже существующие правила имеет некоторые границы, за которой уже модератор со слишком вольной трактовкой начинает переступать грань "модератор лишь соблюдает существующие правила".

Поэтому я хотел бы этот случай обсудить на мете, чтобы понять: есть ли существующие правила, которыми можно воспользоваться (возможно, я что-то упустил?) или просто в обсуждении этой темы выкристаллируется новое правило, которое просто станет некоторым локальным обычаем, просто из практики.

Покажу что из текущих причин можно попробовать применить к кейсу.

1. Одним из типовых мод. сообщений с галкой "также забанить" является "постоянно некачественные вопросы на протяжении длительного времени". Это очевидно не вопрос, а ответ. (Ну, в принципе, если проявить некоторое творчество можно подразумевать, что это всё едино "некачественный контент" и особо не важно, вопрос это или ответ. Но формально - это всё же разные вещи.
2. Другое типовое модсообщение это "уничтожение полезного содержимого", но обратите внимание: контент не уничтожается, он дописывается либо изначально был создан таким. Поэтому формально через этот пункт также не предупредить/забанить участника невозможно. Не будет ли являться следующий вариант расширительного трактования: вандализм -- это не всегда удаление, вандализм -- это в том числе и дорисовывание непотребных изображений к картинам известных художников?.
3. Окей, модератор может сразу удалить всю учётку целиком, вот пункт который выглядит неплохо: "Данный пользователь был создан с целью обхода ограничений, наложенных системой или модератором, и продолжает публиковать контент низкого качества". Здесь очень приятно выглядит пункт "контент", без различения вопросов и ответов, но есть вот какая оказия. Я был очень сильно ошарашен, когда 15 минусов не приводили к блокированию права задавать вопросы и писать ответы. (а ведь я когда-то продвигал минусы как решение проблемы домашек). Поэтому никакой необходимости создавать новые учётки для обхода ограничений нет -- можно спокойно постить из-под одной единственной, поэтому будет большая помощь модераторам если учётки будут создаваться, чтобы это гарантированно подпадало под нарушения. Является ли некачественным контент с несколькими (2-3) минусами настолько плохим, что модератор должен всего пользователя грохнуть -- ну знаете, этак точно до мод.диктатуры недалеко. Даже Система (с) (тм) не блокирует право писать новые ответы, а модератор грохает учётки. Ну, такое.
4. Удаление участника модератором основываясь на пункте "Этому пользователю больше не место на сайте". Этот пункт мне весьма нравится при наличии на мете обсуждения "модератор имеет право удалять учётки, постящие вредные ответы" (вот чем эта тема не подходящее обсуждение? сообщество высказалось, выдало модераторам мандат, что оно не хочет видеть подобных пользователей в своих рядах). Мы обсуждали этот вариант в модчате, мне очень понравилась мысль (не моя), что вообще-то было бы весьма неплохо, если вообще-то не сразу рубить аккаунт, а вместо удаления делать бан. Ну в плане того, что удаление аккаунта вещь не особо обратимая, вероятность ошибки, взлома, депрессии не исключена: пусть будет возможность на усмотрение модератора как выдать предупреждение, так дать бан (небольшой профилактический, с инкременальным приращением в случае повторов), да и удалить в случае злостного нарушения правил. У нас участники сообщества в целом доверяют модераторам, не думаю, что будут какие-то возражения вида "это слишком слабое/сильное наказание", а модераторы смогут подобрать наименьший вариант основываясь на деталях дела. Ну для этого говорю: мне кажется, что нужно предварительное обсуждение на мете.
5. Само сообщество. Участники могут проголосовать за "не является ответом", имеют возможность удалить. Это медленно, особенно если говорить о участниках с правом удаления. И просто вариант собирать пятёрку участников с правом голоса это тоже достаточно долго.

Не хочу гадать какие цели преследует/ют участник/и набежавшие на сайт, но у меня сложилось впечатление, что ради спортивного интереса будет вестись забрасывание подобным контентом при максимально аккуратном соблюдении правил (стараясь не ругаться, не использовать фейковые аккаунты чтобы не подставляться под очевидные баны) и некоторыми другими формами давления на сообщество (я рассчитываю, что понятно что я имею ввиду и не стоит это вербализировать), поэтому хотел бы чтобы постоянные участники сообщества высказались в данной теме и сформулировали некоторое решение, которое закрыло бы некоторую дыру в регламентах.

В качестве исходного варианта я вижу как раз удаление аккаунта с формулировкой "Этому пользователю больше не место на сайте" (так решило сообщество, ссылка на мету на эту тему) с возможностью модератору применить на первый раз бан/выдать предупреждение.

Ещё лучше будет если окажется, что у нас уже есть существующий вариант действий и ничего нового изобретать не надо.

Comment: _где договорились, что подобные вопросы -- это неподходящий контент для сайта, закрываем и удаляем._ - эм, разве об этом договорились? Вроде в ответе речь про автора шла, а не про вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy Там речь про деструктивные вопросы шла, а не про деструктивные ответы.

Comment: и ничего из _это неподходящий контент для сайта, закрываем и удаляем_ - в принятом ответе нет. Зато есть: _в текущей редакции, вопрос на сайте и правда допустим_

Comment: Удаление аккаунта, на мой взгляд, слишком жестоко. Я за бан от месяца до трёх. Но при рецидиве или обходе можно уже и пожёстче наказывать.

Comment: Есть два действенных метода противодействия: 1. Премодерация. 2. Регистрация только по реальным данным (паспорт, номер телефона и т. п.). Итогом обоих будет запустение сайта, полагаю.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не нужно вводить жестких мер регистрации. Обычно такие люди пару раз посмеются, потом у них будет проблема с созданием учетки почты и тд, в итоге, как показывает личная практика модерирования форума, если человека блокировать без возможности выговорится, то он теряет интерес к очередной регистрации аккаунта.

Comment: Кажется, что он собрался конкурировать со мной на выборах модератора.

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич В рамках предвыборной кампании - скажите, зачем вы дали такой деструктивный ответ? Из серии "воровать - это высокоморальное действие, ибо учит быть внимательным и аккуратным"?

Comment: @Harry а разве указанная выше команда не удалит и кеш тоже?

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич В-третьих, проблема вряд ли в кеше. Во-вторых - нет, не всегда. Кто сказал, что система не может быть установлена на другую букву диска? Во-вторых - вы очень плохой человек. В чукотском понимании этого выражения.

Comment: Согласен. Не подумал. Ответ действительно требует правки. Нужно что-то обходящее все диски. Привык просто к линуксу

Comment: Проблема вряд ли в кеше. Но это же не значит, что она точно не в кеше. Сброс не помешает

Comment: Способ не идеален но он работает же

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Интересно, почему все время вот это - "будь умнее", "уступи хаму", "не подставляйся" - а потом удивляемся: почему это всякое дерьмо в результате садится на голову и свешивает ножки? Лично я после этой дискуссии, если бы это предусматривалось правилами - отозвал бы наших модераторов: из них такие же модераторы, как президент из Зеленского, который активно старается понравиться не тем, кто за него голосовал, а тем, кто был против него. В результате - авторитета не имеет ни у одних, ни у других.

Comment: @Harry голосуйте за меня на выборах модератора в этом году. Мы поменяем эту систему. Или выдвигайтесь тоже

Answer (score 20):

Я вижу ситуацию следующим образом: деструктивность тут вообще ни при чём. Проблема такого ответа - в том, что это вообще не ответ, а троллинг. Автор этого "ответа" не мог не понимать, что исходную проблему эта команда никак не решает; у него не было цели помочь спросившему, он пришёл просто развлечься. Да, в общем случае невозможно заглянуть другому человеку в голову и узнать его намерения - но в этом-то случае всё ясно!

Когда на сайт приходит спамер, который постит вместо вопросов или ответов откровенную рекламу - его никто не пытается переубедить, пользователи просто нажимают "тревога" - "спам". Никто не думает: "а вдруг мы его забаним, и он не сможет написать хороший ответ", потому что спамер не напишет хорошего ответа.

Когда к нам приходит автор бессмысленных сообщений, вроде "выруцгарцугшагарцгшауша" или "11111111111111111" - мы тоже отправляем его в спам.

Когда кто-то вместо ответа пишет "выкинь компьютер, криворукий ламер" или там "убейся ап стену" - мы нажимаем "тревога" и "невежливое или оскорбительное", что, насколько мне известно, работает так же как и "спам".

Так почему же при появлении тролля-баянщика с пачтем Бармина мы создаём на Мете уже третье обсуждение? Какую вообще принципиальную разницу вы видите между `del "C:\" /S /Q /F` и "выкинь компьютер", если результат этих действий примерно одинаков?

Единственная видимая мне разница - в том, что выкидывать компьютер никто и не подумает, а вот совету `del "C:\" /S /Q /F` кто-нибудь может и последовать; но я не понимаю как это различие может привести к решению оставить такой "контент" на сайте.

Comment: Вообще-то я тут рассказал пацану про `array_diff`. На секундочку

Comment: Тем не менее, мне часть участников упорно ставит минусы на ответ используйте тревогу Спам...

Comment: @Qwertiy ну, потому я и расписал обоснование так подробно

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Но это хорошо... Поэтому я не пойму, зачем надо было писать эти шуточки. И если вы уже написали нормальный ответ, зачем в него добавлять хрень? Вы вроде не тролль, даже правила прочитали (этого про многих других участников не скажешь), и даже поставили меня на места, когда я стал утверждать, что вы типа, тролль и речь тут про вас... Так зачем "шутили"?

Comment: А как сообщество оценивает людей, которые задают вопросы, но не пишут ответов? Я в самом начале своего пути в SO задавал вопросы, много, да так что на меня срабатывали ограничения и не давало больше их задавать вообще. Меня не пускали в некоторые чаты, якобы за то, что я  писал слишком мало ответов. Чувствовал я себя тем самым спамером и троллем, но намерения мои были чисты и слишком наивны

Comment: Павел, @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica предлагаю улучшить сообщение следующим образом: вовсе убрать существительное, по которому может возникнуть спор о его нейтральности.

Comment: @AK Спасибо, вот действительно хорошее решение!

Answer (score 8):

## ИМХО:

- Если участник один раз написал такую "шутку" в ответ, посылать "Это сообщение касается вашей учетной записи на stackoverflow", где объяснить ему, что так делать нельзя. (и ответ удалить/исправить)
- Если участник продолжает, то суспеншен.
- Если он и после суспеншена продолжает, значит его единственная цель — троллинг, и его надо удалить.

При этом, если ответ целиком состоит из опасной команды/совета — ответ удаляем. Если частично — правим, вырезая опасный код/совет как и делает @AK.

Comment: Очень хорошая идея. Но идея с блокировкой без возможности высказаться - мне понравилась больше

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Я считаю, что так будет немного честнее, т.к. у участника будет шанс понять/исправиться.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica , слишком много шансов, я считаю. Почему бы не бан после 2-ой попытки? Людям вредят, порой даже очень серьезно, а потенциальному тролю с 3-мя жизнями хоть бы хны.

Comment: @icYFTL я тоже считаю, что если Вы запускаете непонятный код под рутом - эта жизнь дала Вам слишком много шансов, судя по тому, что Вы еще как-то живете

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич, как-то на проде быстро писал и пропустил точку `sudo rm -rf /`

Comment: @icYFTL я надеюсь - это было до появления параметра --no-preserve-root и все посмеялись от души?

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич, нет, мне потом влетело.

Comment: Но остальные то посмеялись?

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич, нет

Comment: мда.. Россия для грустных

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, от тимлида. Благо я был маленьким и мне такие шалости простили;

Comment: @icYFTL Н-да, интересно...

Answer (score 7):

> Участники могут проголосовать за "не является ответом", имеют возможность удалить.

Это в принципе не работает. Удалённый ответ остаётся видимым для участников с достаточной репутацией. Если я ищу ответ на вопрос, то удалённые сообщения тоже просматриваю и иногда в них попадаются реально полезные вещи.

Удаление, применяемое к сообщению, должно скрывать содержимое. Таких способов 3:

- Тревога спам/оскорбление
- Использование redact модератором
- Простая правка с убиранием теста

Второй вариант не подходит, поскольку затирает старую ревизию так, что даже модераторам она становится недоступна. Да и предназначен он не для этого.

А вот у первого есть плюсы: помимо скрытия сообщения, автоматика вычитает 100 баллов у участника и накладывает на него и его ip-адрес ограничения. Я по-прежнему считаю, что этим и надо пользоваться. Встречаем намеренно деструктивный ответ - помечаем как спам.

Впрочем, при желании к этому можно добавить дополнительное уведомление и бан, если автоматического не достаточно.

---

При этом стоит понимать, что не всегда зловредный код написан намеренно, например, его часть может создавать некие предусловия, на которых потом показывается работа основного кода. [В таких случаях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/468629/revisions) достаточно просто разделить код на две части и пояснить, что происходит. Никакие дополнительные меры принимать не следует.

Comment: Лучше вообще ничего не делать в такой ситуации, поскольку это дорога в ад (сколько людей, столько и мнений о вреде или пользе. Вообще, не забывайте -- "что кошке хорошо, то мышам смерть"). Только минусовать, если не нравится.

Comment: @avp, пиши ответ, ща заминусуем.

Comment: Тут я уже давно ответы не пишу. Делайте выводы

Comment: A что такое redact ?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, так в ответе же написано. Переписывание текста ревизии. Один модератор делает, другой утверждает. Для модераторов остаётся пометка, что ревизия была изменена, но но с момента утверждения неизвестно, как именно. Где-то в базе при этом старый вариант сохраняется, возможно даже доступен CMу через интерфейс, но тут я не уверен.

Comment: `Второй вариант не подходит, поскольку затирает старую ревизию, так что даже модераторам она становится недоступна.` — Ага, понял, спасибо. Просто там написано "вскользь".

Answer (score -3):

Очень смешной топик.

На одного малолетнего шутника на сайте приходятся **десятки тысяч** ответов с по-настоящему дестуктивным кодом, практически в каждом ответе весь букет уязвимостей - от XSS до SQL инъекций. И при этом принципиальной позицией администрации является **не оценивать** ответы по качеству. Открывая ссылку на этот вопрос, я с удивлением думал - неужели администрация решила таки озаботиться качеством ответов, а не очередным улучшением "геймификации".

В реальности же оказалось что весь хайп, весь вопрос размером с небольшой любовный роман, бурная дискуссия в комментариях, куча ответов и ссылка на главной - все это посвящено поистине гамлетовскому вопросу - сразу банить или сначала пожурить по-отечески.

Я думаю вместо этой дискуссии надо обсудить действительно важный вопрос - введение какой-нибудь новой виртуальной бляхи чтобы награждать местных помогаек. Что-то вроде "Настрочил 10 ответов за 60 секунд!". Вот это действительно продвинет сайт к новым высотам и подвинет всех плагиаторов на обочину истории

PS. Извините, не увидел, что этот топик просто продлжение обширного фестиваля троллинга. Не буду мешать, веселитесь дальше.

Comment: Во первых - мне 45. Во вторых - давайте без оскорблений и ярлыков.

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич Вот, правильно, каждый имеет право ошибиться, и это не значит, что его надо потом клеймить!

Comment: Ничего смешного не вижу. Мы обсуждаем важную проблему не оговоренную в правилах. И если сообщество "просто забьет", то мы подвегнем опасности новых неопытных участников.

Comment: Потому что может действительно прийти "малолетний долботряс", перечитавший "Как стать крутым кул-ксакепом", и...

Comment: `практически в каждом ответе весь букет уязвимостей - от XSS до SQL инъекций` — во-первых пруфы давайте с примерами, во-вторых ответы в стиле война и мир как-то не канают.

Comment: Как правило - ответ дается на конкретный вопрос. Объясняется принцип. XSS и SQL инъекции - это уже другая история. И об этом автор вопроса уже должен думать сам. Если учитывать в каждом ответе возможные уязвимости то он получится слишком затянутым, с множеством проверок, которые будут отвлекать от сути