# "Бан, но не бан" — а тогда что это и какие его последствия?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, блокировка, модераторский-произвол

[01.12.2020 Модератором Barmaley был написан следующий комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11153/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%90-%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5#comment47373_11153) (выделение жирным — мое):

> Понимаю, что меня никто не слушает, тем не менее изложу свою точку зрения: 1) это не только мое решение, а коллегиальное решение нескольких модераторов. Забанены несколько участников дискуссии. 2) предлагается просто успокоиться - мы обязательно вернемся к дискуссии, решение сейчас вырабатывается в модераторском сообществе **3) это не бан (безусловно по форме бан), а просто способ успокоиться всем и нам и вам.**

У меня возник законный вопрос о том, что же такое "бан, но не бан", который "безусловно по форме бан". В частности:

1. Чем он отличается от "обычного бана"?
2. Помешает ли такой бан в течение года номинироваться [его получившим] на позицию модератора?

Замечания:

- Публично баны конкретных участников обсуждать не принято, особенно с другими участниками. Мой вопрос — касательно формулировки и общего принципа таких банов.
- Если возникает такая модераторская практика (а я не уверен в том, что прецеденты "банов, но не банов" были уже), нужно понять, что за ней стоит.
- Чего бы я точно не хотел — это чтобы этот пост свёлся к обсуждению конкретных действий заблокированных необычным способом пользователей в этот раз.

Comment: Он отличается от обычного "бана" демагогическим заявлением модератора - "это не бан". А раз "это не бан", значит и возмущаться и возражать нет причины. "просто способ успокоиться всем и нам и вам" - "забаньте" тогда себя. Но почему-то не "забанивают". Вероятно, нет технической возможности.

Comment: @Igor напомнило [**"когда убьют тогда и приходите"**](https://life.ru/p/1354859)

Answer (score 15):

Это называется буря в стакане воды.

У участников закрытых сообществ, таких например как завсегдатаи сайта Stack Overflow на русском META, часто появляется тенденция к преувеличению значимости обсуждаемых проблем. Им кажется, что они спасают мир и без их бдительности всё придёт в негодность. В реальности же проблемы оказываются совершенно банальными и вызваны исключительно излишним рвением участников, в ту или иную сторону.

Как человек с богатым опытом получения банов на стаковерфлое, я могу сказать что два раза формальный повод для годичного бана был вообще ни о чём, но при этом я осознаю что по совокупности, плюс заработанная репутация и проблемы в коммуникации вполне могли потянуть на такой срок. То есть банов совсем без причины не бывает.

Я не в первый раз наблюдаю этот театр на русской мете, когда некоторые участники развлекаются проверкой правил на прочность. Я понимаю что сообщество маленькое, всем скучно и все с азартом [включаются в эту игру](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10617/179379).

Или как сейчас - модераторы на цырлах пляшут вокруг троллей, стараясь одновременно и не совсем разогнать чахлое коммьюнити, и как-то унять самых буйных. А им же за это и предьявляют самозваные правозащитники, "а покажите букву в правилах, по которой его забанили!"

В принципе проблема известная, и решение стандартное - "не обсуждать бойцовский клуб". Любая попытка оспаривать действия модераторов приводит к бану. Да, у этого есть негативная сторона, без общесвенного контроля модераторы тоже портятся. Но на данный момент я считаю что модерирование на русо слишком мягкое, и особенно это касается горлопанов на мете.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117334/discussion-on-answer-by--------------).

Answer (score 0):

> что же такое "бан, но не бан", который "безусловно по форме бан"

Могу только предположить, что это какой-то новый инструмент модератора: ***когда очень хочется, но нет "за что"***.

Очень надеюсь, что скоро мы получим хоть какое-то вразумительное разъяснение этого загадочного выражения. Однако, меня больше беспокоит другое (выделил жирным):

> Понимаю, что меня никто не слушает, тем не менее изложу свою точку
> зрения: **1) это не только мое решение, а коллегиальное решение
> нескольких модераторов.** Забанены несколько участников дискуссии. 2)
> предлагается просто успокоиться - мы обязательно вернемся к дискуссии,
> решение сейчас вырабатывается в модераторском сообществе 3) это не бан
> (безусловно по форме бан), а просто способ успокоиться всем и нам и
> вам.

Если это фантастическое заявление является мнением, и как следствие решением, одного только модератора, то это не совсем страшно. Но если это действительно коллегиальное решение, то здесь уже стоит задуматься. Задуматься "*всем и нам и вам*".

---

Anton Menshov, спасибо вам за этот вопрос. Как с языка сняли (¬‿¬)

Comment: Как бывший модератор: - бан по совокупности мелких нарушений code of conduct - это нормально. Но это должно быть явно обозначено в личном сообщении о бане, и должны быть приведены примеры этих мелких нарушений.

Comment: @PashaPash более чем согласен.

Comment: @PashaPash, а мне почему-то кажется, что ничего в результате не поменяется. И от этого становится только грустно.

Comment: Скажу больше, бан за несогласие с модератором тоже у нас _нормально_.

Comment: Решение банить обоих было принято более чем одним модератором, т. е. эта строчка - правда.

Comment: @Qwertiy, за остальных модераторов ничего сказать не могу, не знаю. Но что касается вас, то всегда был уверен в справедливости ваших решений.

Comment: @Sevastopol', я вообще к принятию решению опоздал...

Comment: @Qwertiy все равно виноват!

Comment: @Sevastopol' если по теме - вам пришло личное сообщение о бане. если в нем не расписано, за что именно бан - на него стоит ответить и попросить пояснений.

Comment: @PashaPash, в [личном сообщении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11181/377637) была указана причина - агрессия, которой с моей стороны никогда не было.

Comment: @Sevastopol' стоило бы ответить на это сообщение и попросить пояснений, что именно в вашем было воспринято как агрессия. Публичные разборки на мете - тупиковый путь.

Comment: @Qwertiy т.е. решение приняли Бармалей с Грунди? )

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, без комментариев.

Comment: @Qwertiy от нас умалчивают правду (¬‿¬ )