# Все успокоились. Какое выработалось решение?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, блокировка

У меня три абсолютно законных вопроса в связи с [комментарием модератора @Barmaley♦](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11153/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%90-%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5#comment47373_11153):

> Понимаю, что меня никто не слушает, тем не менее изложу свою точку
> зрения: 1) это не только мое решение, а коллегиальное решение
> нескольких модераторов. Забанены несколько участников дискуссии. 2)
> предлагается просто успокоиться - мы обязательно вернемся к дискуссии,
> решение сейчас вырабатывается в модераторском сообществе 3) это не бан
> (безусловно по форме бан), а просто способ успокоиться всем и нам и
> вам.

**Предыстория:** Участником @AntonMenshov ранее был задан совершенно справедливый вопрос [“Бан, но не бан” — а тогда что это и какие его последствия?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11178/377637) касательно формулировки "*это не бан (безусловно по форме бан)*", которая является открытым заявлением и уточнением модератора, объясняющим блокирование учетных записей участников сообщества. Такая формулировка мне не понятна, хотя я и пытался ее расшифровать. К сожалению, каких-либо разъяснений от модераторов на этот счет так и не поступило, и вопрос остался без ответа.

**Первый вопрос:** Что означает формулировка "*это не бан (безусловно по форме бан), а просто способ успокоиться всем и нам и вам.*"?

...Прошло время. Успокоились все и мы и вы. В связи с чем у меня возникли еще два вопроса.

**Второй вопрос:** К какой дискуссии мы обязательно должны были или будем вернуться?

**Третий вопрос:** Какое решение должно было или будет или уже выработалось в модераторском сообществе?

---

**Важно:** Прошу не минусовать на эмоциях, а постараться ответить на вопросы. Все три вопроса для меня важны, и я, как участник сообщества, вправе получить на них ответы, потому как они касаются и моей учетной записи в том числе, а также, что самое главное, последствий такого "бана но не бана".

Comment: Есть некоторые разъяснения [здесь](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117334/discussion-on-answer-by--------------). Превентивно прошу всех участников дискуссии быть уважительными друг к другу вне зависимости от согласия\несогласия с другим мнением.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, спасибо за ссылку. Да, я уже читал эти комментарии. Однако, мне хотелось бы получить какие-то, так сказать, официальные ответы на все эти вопросы, потому как там я их не нашел. Там только споры, ругань и оскорбления от некоторых участников. Мне не хотелось бы опускаться до такого уровня. Я с уважением отношусь как к себе, так и ко всем участникам сообщества.

Comment: 1) непонятно, что конкретно вас смущает в формулировке про бан? 2) почему вы думаете, что ответы на остальные вопросы вообще есть у кого то? 3) есть ли какая то причина ждать ответа от модераторов, учитывая что на предыдущие вопросы ответа нет неделями? 4) почему эти вопросы нельзя задать модератором в чате или личке. В чем польза сообществу обсуждать это заново?

Comment: Если вы хотите получить официальные ответы, то это рекомендуется делать не на мете, а через форму обратной связи. Напишите, эту форму читают и реагируют: без шумихи и пиара, снаружи не особо видно, но процедура достаточно чёткая. Мне кстати весьма импонирует традиция, которую ввел один модератор, что на период внутреннего расследования он взял мод. отпуск и ждал итогов. Как сейчас не знаю, но то, что не видно снаружи - не значит, что работа в мод.корпусе и администрации не идёт.

Comment: @AK, ответы на эти вопросы, а особенно касается формулировок и последствий таких блокировок в будущем безусловно будут полезны всем участникам сообщества. Поэтому открыто, а не через форму обратной связи.

Comment: @tym32167, 1) А вас не смущает такая формулировка? 2) Кто написал этот комментарий, явно понимал, о чем он написал. 3) Я надеюсь, что ответы будут. По крайней мере, как минимум это справедливо. 4) Ответы на эти вопросы, а особенно касается формулировок и последствий таких блокировок в будущем безусловно будут полезны всем участникам сообщества. Поэтому открыто, а не через форму обратной связи.

Comment: Я присоединяюсь к мнению A K о форме обратной связи. Для вас, как для непосредственного участника инцидента — это абсолютно оправданный шаг. Что-то можно и нужно разбирать публично, что-то можно разобрать и приватно (во всяком случае изначально).

Comment: К слову так, возможно именно вы и опубликуете наиболее содержательный ответы на свои (может и на мой) вопросы по итогам всего этого. Или нет.

Comment: Anton Menshov, AK, возможно, вы конечно и правы. Я попробую задать все эти вопросы через форму обратной связи. Просьба, подскажите, пожалуйста следующее: имеется ввиду форма на странице [https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), верно? И какую тему мне выбрать, какой вариант будет самым верным на ваш взгляд? Спасибо.

Comment: @Sevastopol' ссылка правильная.

Comment: Не согласен ни с АК, ни с новым для меня участником Anton Menshov. 
Форма обратной связи - это лишь визуальная точка взаимодействия с самим сообществом. Никакой практической пользы она не несёт. 
Коллеги, занимающиеся ru направлением крайне редко реагируют вообще на какие-либо сообщения. Один Николас пытается что-то делать. 
И это я говорю, не из головы, а так как у меня есть достаточно большой опыт общения с сотрудниками stackoverflow. 
На любой спорный вопрос, подобный заданному Sevastopol, Вы получите ответ - пусть решает сообщество.

Comment: @Sevastopol` Так что я считаю, что это именно общественный вопрос, который, в очередной раз, был несправедливо заблокирован. 
Причём оцените иронию....
Кто-то берёт отпуск на время расследования, а кто-то не допускает такого расследования блокируя любые сообщения о себе. 

Не напоминает ли Вам это ничего?
Снова тоталитарный режим?

Если уж пеняешь на свободу, то она должна быть абсолютная, а не в рамках тех, кому это выгодно и удобно.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, ну отсылка к вопросу, на который якобы уже даны ответы (типа дубликат что ли), мягко выразиться как минимум смущает. Вижу это так - любыми средствами закрыть рот участнику. Конечно напоминает)