# Просьба сократить срок блокировки участника

Tags: поддержка, блокировка

Сегодня был заблокирован [**@Ипатьев**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179379).
Судя по формулировке бана из профиля (цитирую: *"с целью дать участнику успокоиться"*), она указывает на какие-то высказывания участника как причину блокировки.
Если эта трактовка верна, то блок сроком на месяц выглядит ***чрезмерно*** жесткой мерой.

Ведь есть ряд нюансов:

- Участник активно приносит пользу сообществу, что очевидно по его профилям на ruSO и enSO
- Некоторым людям по характеру свойственна резкость выражений, это еще не говорит о каком-то злом умысле
- Хоть неприкасаемых и нет, завышенные меры по отношению к уважаемым участникам (при отсутствии мер к безусловно отрицательным элементам, например к спамящим клоноводам) могут вызвать массовый и резко негативный отклик сообщества, что может вылиться в новые нарушения

##### Пожалуйста, приведите срок блокировки в соответствие с нарушением.

Если причина действительно в импульсивно-необдуманных действиях участника, то примерно 48 часов будет более чем достаточно для того чтобы успокоиться.
Да и как минимум честно будет применять прогрессивное усиление мер (например, предупреждение  штраф репутации или readonly  короткая блокировка  продленная блокировка).

Акцентирую, что дело тут не в конкретном участнике (месячный бан на "успокоение" сам по себе шокирует, к кому бы это ни применялось), и поэтому прошу не отменять решение или объяснять его, а только скорректировать меру наказания по справедливости.

Comment: Не уверен что такие обращения стоит писать через Мету (первый опыт), сорри если кто-то сочтет этот пост раздражающим или неуместным.

Comment: "если кто-то сочтет этот пост", он может обратиться в Лигу сексуальных реформ. Поддерживаю.

Comment: _Да и как минимум честно будет применять прогрессивное усиление мер (например, предупреждение  штраф репутации или readonly  короткая блокировка  продленная блокировка)._ - почему предполагается, что сейчас должна быть коротка блокировка, а не уже продленная?

Comment: @Grundy, потому что предполагается еще и определенный лимит сроков бана по типу нарушения. То есть, например(!), за провокации - до 7 дней бана, за явно намеренную порчу чужих постов - до 30 дней, за преследование/угрозы расправы - до перманента, и так далее. Тут я предположил что заблокировали за обычные для этого участника критические замечания к контенту высказанные слишком эмоционально, и месячный срок бана воспринимается слишком суровым наказанием за такой (не самый страшный) проступок. Но фактов о нарушении не знаю, конечно, и поэтому прошу только рассмотреть случай внимательнее.

Comment: Если не знаете фактов, зачем делать громкие заявления? По прогрессивной шкале у Ипатьева уже вечный бан должен быть...

Comment: @yar85 блокировки обычно по нарастающей идут: 1 сутки, 3 дня, неделя, месяц,  N месяцев, год, forever. На сколько я помню Ипатьев уже был на год забанен, так что сейчас действительно должен быть уже в вечном бане. Видимо когда-то была амнистия и всем скинули сроки)) Так что это уже дабл рецедив)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, Во-первых, о каких "громких заявлениях" речь? Во-вторых, о чем говорит последний параграф в вопросе (ты его вообще прочел, или не озаботившись пониманием смысла сразу кинулся упрекать меня и осуждать Ипатьева)?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вообще меня удивил не сам бан, а именно его срок, мера наказания. **Если** действительно назначили срок исходя их прошлых нарушений участника (придав им большее значение, чем последнему нарушению), то это удручает... т.к. думаю что каждый заслуживает возможности исправиться. Но даже если так, разочарование это уже мои личные проблемы, и признаю свою ошибку - общее предположение о справедливости к участникам было совсем необоснованным (о ней нигде не заявлено). Впредь постараюсь быть осторожнее с предположениями.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, _«блокировки обычно по нарастающей идут: 1 сутки, 3 дня, неделя, месяц, N месяцев, год, forever»_ - вот как раз то, чего я не понимал, думая что система оценки несколько другая используется (с бóльшим весом других факторов, таких как характер проступка). Огромное спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: @yar85 ну может быть есть какие-то более широкие критерии. Но если нарушения регулярные - то идёт 100% увеличение. Иначе было бы странно, что каждый раз кого-то оскорбив и получив сутки блока, по сути, можно было бы постоянно так легко отделываться

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, _«Иначе было бы странно»_ - у разных людей разное мнение на этот счет :) Мне вот странной кажется как раз возможность "дослужиться" мелкими проступками до перманента (проводя аналогию, это как казнить человека если объем всех бумажек брошенных им мимо урны в течение жизни превысит N - по сути та же логика). Но порядки такие как есть, и мнения рядовых участников не влияют, так что нет и смысла их обсуждать (имхо).

Comment: @yar85, перманентные банов практически не используются. Обычно ограничиваются годовыми.

Comment: А что означает `по отношению к уважаемым участникам`? В нашем сообществе есть неуважаемые участники? Г-н yar85, не пытаетесь ли вы случаем мерять рангом всех участников. По мне, так это что-то новенькое. Или мне показалось?

Comment: @Sevastopol', Это и означает. Да, есть (см. пример клоноводов-спамеров). Показалось - что именно, о каком из предшествующих предложений задан вопрос?

Comment: Будь я модер, я б удвоил

Comment: Я думаю вам будет интересно почитать [этот пост на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11199/337980)

Comment: @AntonMenshov, спасибо, уже видел ранее. Связи этого поста с этим своим запросом не понимаю - т.к. тут самогó нарушителя не оправдывал и не осуждал (что не мешает другим участникам этим заниматься), хоть и обратил внимание на его заслуги как на факт; и блокировку как таковую не оспаривал (попросил не отменять бан, а лишь сделать срок наказания соответствующим нарушению). Конечно, притянуть эти два поста друг к другу вполне можно, но это будет (мягко говоря) не совсем корректно.

Comment: В конце концов, просто не разделяю мнение Ипатьева относительно "бури в стакане", и считаю прецеденты важными: т.к. никому из участников ruSO не желаю получать месячные+ баны за слова (помимо спамеров, которых считать участниками сообщества можно лишь условно). Сообщество вполне может считать такую позицию ошибочной - но стоит ли вступать в противостояние? Ведь я не пытаюсь тут кого-то "обратить", да и пишу от первого лица, а не за всех / за группу. Раз ответ модератора получен, думаю что пора заканчивать с этим здесь (случай-то исчерпан, а обсуждение лучше будет открыть отдельным вопросом).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Не спорю, что г-н @Ипатьев, полезный член сообщества. Его ответы, комментарии профессиональны и по делу. Но... Товарищ грубоват, я бы даже сказал груб, если не сказать хам. Вы почитайте его комментарии, если он встал не с той ноги, то все, пиши пропало, первый попавшийся автор будет вознагражден порцией ругани и мата.

Неоднократно беседовал(и) с ним. Он каялся, говорил, что больше не будет:

> Спасибо, я постараюсь. Хотя очень трудно сдерживаться. Количество невежества и неадекватности просто зашкаливает.

Как итог 7 блокировок (4-мя разными модераторами, 3 раза на 7 дней, 3 раза на 30 дней, 1 раз на год), 3 предупреждения.

Согласен, что действительно количество невежества и неадеквата в ruSO, особенно в последнее время реально зашкаливает, но это не повод. Как мне говорил один мой руководитель:

> Не уподобляйтесь.

Comment: Интерпретирую ответ как "Просьба рассмотрена, пересмотра срока не будет учитывая личность нарушителя". Спасибо за ответ, принято.

Comment: @yar85 Учитывая не личность нарушителя, а историю взаимодействия нарушителя с сообществом. Это важно.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, да, спасибо за поправку, я неправильно написал: учитывается не личность, а **характеристика** участнику, выведенная из истории его нарушений - т.к. и ответ, и комментарии акцентируют именно на рецидивах/неоднократности (обходя такие факторы как давность и "класс" нарушений). Другими словами, получается что судят в первую очередь по прошлому участника, а не по настоящему. Тут я не утверждаю что предвзятость суждений обязательно плоха, только резюмирую прочитаное.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, что в целом я согласен с осужденным, но проблема в том, что такие высказывания допустимы в частной беседе, за стаканчиком кофе/пива, но в сообществе это недопустимо. Закон есть закон. [Dura lex, sed lex](http://chtooznachaet.ru/dura-lex-sed-lex.html)

Comment: @Barmaley, по высказываниям - это безусловно верно. Насмешки и выскомерие трудно назвать допустимыми, даже в шутливом/ироничном тоне (т.к. реципиент не всегда способен распознать шутливый тон). Тут некоторые даже на нейтральное замечание к вопросу реагируют как на личное оскорбление, т.к. изначально приходят с ожиданием сервисной услужливости или "поглаживаний" (по Э.Берну).

Comment: Надеюсь, когда-нибудь сообщество станет проявлять понимание не только к потерпевшей стороне, и появится "мода" на ровное отношение без перекосов. А то получается что заносчивость обиженных сообществом оберегается, а заносчивость обидчиков осуждается - хотя разницы между ними имхо нет: видел множество случаев когда обиженный в отсутствие обидчика сам легко входит в противоположную роль и начинает словесно атаковать доброжелательных участников за мнимые оскорбления (типа "как ты посмел вообще что-то писать под моим контентом"). И это практически во всех виденных случаях оставалось безнаказанным.

Comment: @yar85 я по мере сил стараюсь не реагировать на мнимые оскорбления и сношу такие тревоги как необоснованные.