# Как узнать конкретную причину блокировки?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, блокировка, модераторский-произвол

Сразу скажу на `"Stackoverflow Meta"` я в первые и не знаю можно ли задавать тут такие вопросы, но мне все же интересно узнать ответ.

Расскажу всю историю:

3 дня назад я получил блокировку на аккаунт по причине `"проявления невежливости"`. Я впервые столкнулся с блокировкой, но прочитал что могу обжаловать её. Но я не понимал, за что конкретно мне дали блокировку.
Я на протяжении двух недель адекватно помогал авторам вопросов и тут мне дают блокировку.

Через 3 минуты после получения бана сразу ответил модераторам, где написал, что хочу узнать конкретно за что меня заблокировали. Не дождавшись ответа я решил написал на почту. Написал я 2 сообщения но ответа я все еще не получил. Думал ну ладно блокировка пройдет, буду ждать пока скажут за что блокировку дали, как минимум, чтобы не повторять ошибок (хотя повторюсь я все еще не понимаю где за мной было замечено `"проявления невежливости"`).

И т.к. я не сталкивался ранее с баном аккаунта, я был удивлен что и репутацию мне всю отобрали. И теперь у меня нет мотивации помогать другим. (Да для меня репутация важна, т.к. это показывает мне, что я не просто сижу на сайте и просиживаю штаны, а действительно помогаю людям)

Я нигде не нашел информацию про то, что репутацию при блокировке отбирают и думаю может её не сразу просто возвращают?

Так же мне интересно все же узнать, конкретную причину блокировки т.к. я уверен, что я мог бы её обжаловать. (не знаю может я не заметил и матом покрыл кого-то)

Подскажите если не здесь, то где я могу получить ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117742/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Очевидно, модератор (это был не @Barmaley) принял во внимание следующее обстоятельство (см скриншот ниже):
2. Без комментариев

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если это первое нарушение, и раньше с участником не связывались, то на бан это не тянет.

Comment: Нет, увы не первое нарушение - за ним тянется шлейф нарушений - не скажу что очень большой, но по совокупности тянет на бан. Несколько тревог выставленных разными юзерами за 3-4 дня + тревога робота + своеобразная общая лексическая нагрузка сообщений... Я думаю, модератор провел быстрое следствие и принял свое решение. Ну по мне все достаточно очевидно. Так что я поддержу коллегу модератора.

Comment: Интересно. Значит автор поста умолчал про историю прошлых сообщений с модераторами)

Comment: Ранее, насколько я вижу с юзером не общались, просто удаляли его сообщения/комментарии. В какой то момент видимо решили что хватит и дали бан на 3 дня.

Comment: Если с ним не связывались, то он может даже не знать, что его сообщения удалялись. Уведомлений же никаких нет.

Comment: @Barmaley ничего себе. Оказывается я давно нарушаю уже. Я думал, что общаюсь в порядке вещей, вроде без оскорблений и нормально, оказывается... Спасибо что объяснили причину бана.

Comment: Как мне кажется на первый взгляд, в этих комментариях нет ничего особенно оскорбительного. Да, моменты грубости местами присутствуют, но мы не видим комментарии второго собеседника, чтобы утверждать, оправдано ли такое построение диалога или нет. Могу с уверенностью сказать, что от одного из модераторов как-то не так давно были более грубые комментарии, содержащие действительно оскорбительный характер, и при этом никто никого не банил за такие выпады. Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik, вам ничего это случайно не напоминает? :)

Comment: `это был не @Barmaley` ­— это был @Grundy взломавший аккаунт настоящего Бармалея и выдавший себя тем, что говорит о себе в третьем лице. ;D

Comment: В очередной раз убеждаюсь в бессмысленности ответов на мете :)

Comment: Почему? Всех ответ удовлетворил вроде... Теперь все ясно.

Comment: Настоящим злодеем оказался не тот, на кого все думали. Неожиданная кульминация, хоть фильм в Голливуде снимай.

Answer (score 8):

> N.B. В настоящее время я не являюсь представителем модсостава, поэтому
> прошу рассматривать этот пост исключительно как выражение личного мнения.

В первую очередь мне очень жаль, что настоящий кейс дошёл до мета-сайта. Это правда, что модераторы не обязаны отчитываться перед участниками, но если бы участник получил предупреждение и только при повторении получил бы реальный бан -- то на мой взгляд шансы на то, что тема не появилась бы на мете и не портила бы имидж представителей сообщества были бы намного выше.

Андрей верно говорит в комментариях, что в предыдущем составе мы делали большой упор на профилактическую работу. Просто [посмотрите на цифры](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucz7r.png) выписанных мод.сообщений, львиная доли их -- предупреждения, а не "получите-распишитесь, вот вам бан". (Я расходился с Андреем только в одном пункте:  предпочитал дотошно вставлять ссылку и цитату на нарушение, а Андрей не такой бюрократ. С учётом того, что предупреждения писались по горячим следам, то в большинстве случаев вопросов "за что????" не возникало, ну возникало -- цитировали)

Не раскрывая всех подробностей могу сказать, что в подавляющем большинстве участники на сайте люди адекватные и вполне понимали и а) за что предупреждают и б) больше с ними подобные случаи не повторялись. Какие-то отдельные случаи повторных рецидивов бывали, но это настолько редко, что хватит пальцев одной руки чтобы пересчитать. (Плюс если предупреждение было больше чем месяц назад, а повтор случился позже -- начинали цикл сначала: новое предупреждение, если прошел месяц а жалоб нет -- считали инцидент закрытым.)

Бан сразу или даже удаление учётки -- это надо что-то очень серьёзное сделать, таких случаев было много всегда, но как правило это сценарии которые ни у кого не вызывают сомнений: например, когда постят очевидный спам, либо когда появляется новичок и сразу обкладывает всех трёхэтажным. Никто на такое в здравом уме не приходил ещё жаловаться на модераторов, вот вообще ни одного случая не было, так что мы тоже выписывали баны без особых затруднений и учётки удаляли тоже без угрызений совести. (Банить спустя полгода после того как дали ромб очень легко, быстро привыкаешь: это ещё один из аргументов почему я предпочёл уйти пока глаз не замылился)

И я не знаю вот, как было дело в этом случае... это вам только те, кто сейчас ромб имеют может подробнее пояснить. Я думаю, что самый простой вариант был бы: попросить в мод.теме в которой вам забанили привести конкретные примеры нарушений. Либо там всё очевидно и вы сами вспомните что это был за случай и самому станет стыдно за написанное, либо вы посмотрите и скажете "не убедило" -- и вот тогда лучше писать этажом выше, уже в администрацию.

Шансом прояснить у самих модераторов лучше не пренебрегать, это дополнительный вариант узнать детали, а главное -- это способ намного более быстрый. Модераторов несколько, переписку видит каждый из них.

Кроме того, модераторы тоже люди, иногда ошибаются, у меня был как минимум один случай, когда я выписал предупреждение и потом там же в мод. теме выяснилось, что я был не прав. Хорошо, что этот случай тогда не попал на мету, а так бы попал - люди меньше идеализировали бы предыдущий состав.

В общем, такой подход когда а) модераторы предупреждают и б) участники сначала уточняют детали в мод.теме и только в случае сильных разногласий выплёскивают в публичное пространство на мету (на мой взгляд: лучше -- предварительно уточнив через официальный канал, но тут мнения у всех разные) я считаю весьма удачным.

Не знаю правда, есть ли возможность донести эту точку зрения и до модераторов (они не обязаны прислушиваться ко всему что написано на мете и это тоже правильно) и до каждого участника (где-то же в справке описан рекомендуемый порядок урегулирования споров по банам, да?), но вот как-то так я вижу и конкретный кейс и аналогичные.

И я отдельно хочу ещё раз подчеркнуть вот какой момент. Возможно, в большинстве случаев подобные славные традиции и продолжаются до сих пор, для того, чтобы судить это было один раз на тысячу или один раз из двух -- надо иметь доступ к статистике изнутри мод.состава, а снаружи мы можем фиксировать только то, что просочилось в публичное поле не зная всей картины.

Когда-то у меня было предложение: дать доступ к мод.чату участникам имеющим репутацию выше 10к, однако поскольку в мод.чате постоянно пролетает личная информация то пришлось бы собирать с каждого согласие эквивалентное модераторскому. Не прошло моё предложение :( возможно, надо было на метамету с этим идти и предлагать на уровне всей сети вводить подобный уровень прозрачности модераторов.

У меня всё пожалуй, что есть сказать. Если будут вопросы по тексту -- пишите в комментариях, постараюсь ответить.

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен. Написанное можно охарактеризовать одним предложением - всё должно быть по справедливости. Или просто по человечески. Что касается прозрачности, то это конечно полезная в идеале была бы практика. Но здесь увы, в этом случае кто-то из мод.состава может почувствовать себя ущемленным. В целом же, я не вижу здесь на SO никаких различий от других подобных ресурсов в плане поведения модераторов. Как и везде - "я здесь царь и Бог, и для меня это унизительно простому участнику прокомментировать свои действия". Не все такие, конечно, не все. Но некоторые, самые активные.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Вижу чуть иначе. Квертий говорил "банит не один Бармалей", но злым полицейским ему долго быть, так и будут дальше демонизировать и проецировать в него одного всё плохое. Там где вы видите "не отвечает, потому что я царь и бог" я склонен видеть "у модераторов просто не хватает времени" (да, бывают модераторы типа Юры или Андрея, которые просто пылесосят флаги каждые три минуты, но это лишь исключения, обычно модератор занят работой, семьёй) и "модераторы совещаются" (иногда проходила неделя, пока всех соберёшь). Снаружи же видно только "молчат", а "корона жмёт" - это лишь домыслы.

Comment: Да, банит не один Бармалей. Нет, нисколько не демонизирую и не думаю только о плохом. Знаю и видел также и положительные качества по моему мнению и решения Бармалея. Но, к сожалению, есть одно но. С уверенностью могу сказать, что на некоторые вопросы нет ответов принципиально, а не от занятости семьей, потому как за определенный период, за который возможно было бы что-то прокомментировать, наблюдаю активность там, где она, на мой взгляд, не настолько важна как для модератора. Отсюда и складывается не совсем приятное мнение в отношении модерирования. Нужно быть не злым полицейским, а открытым.

Comment: Вот тут да, полностью согласен.

Comment: АК, еще хотелось бы добавить. Я не говорю модератору, что ты, например меня, забанил несправедливо. Я не задаю ему вопрос - почему или зачем. Я модератора прошу - конкретизируй причину моей блокировки согласно указанной причине в письме и своему же пояснению в комментариях. Приведи конкретные примеры, где я был настолько не прав в своем поведении, за что я заслужил бан. Впрочем как и этот вопрос, на который вы нашли время написать ответ, но почему-то у модераторов на ответ время не находится. Если вопрос выносится на Мету, то реакция модераторов должна быть мгновенной. Неужели я не прав?

Comment: @Sevastopol' не мгновенной. Но должна последовать. "Должна" здесь использовано не с точки зрения обязанностей, а с точки зрения человеческой и общественно полезной. В противном случае, сложно "предполагать добрые намерения".

Comment: То, что описано здесь, выглядит как неумеренно мягкий подход к модерации. Даже на форумах модерация была более жесткой, а у нас вопросов больше, требования качеству выше, а модераторов меньше. В частности, в июне участник намеренно публиковал вредоносный код в завуалированном виде: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/ , но забанили его только после того, как он опубликовал на мете что-то неполиткорректное. Его тоже предупреждали несколько раз? Боюсь, это свидетельствует о полной несостоятельности этого подхода. Реальная модерация - кнут и пряник в пропорции примерно 10:1.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, реальная модерация, как мне кажется, это не жесткая модерация, это не кнут и пряник, а индивидуальный, продуманный, справедливый и оправданный в смысле правил и человеческого взаимоотношения подход к ситуации в каждом конкретном случае (к каждому участнику). Ну как минимум из уважения к участнику. А то, о чем пишите вы про реальную модерацию, это царские времена. Ну да, того участника, который многих подверг опасности своим кодом, забанили куда позже, чем например Андрея, который написал в отношении меня всего лишь пару оскорбительных комментариев.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, ну пусть и не мгновенной, допустим человеческий фактор. Но всё верно, именно с точки зрения человечности и взаимоуважения, а не обязанностей. Я не про обязанности, никто здесь никому ничем не обязан. Я про: ребята, давайте жить дружно и давайте уважать друг друга. Если задан вопрос, то прояви уважение и напиши ответ. Забудь, что ты модератор, это только лишь тебе кажется, что на твоей голове корона, но это совсем не так. А вот открытое игнорирование и низкие приемы это и есть откровенное проявление неуважения к участнику твоего же сообщества. Вот я о чем.