# Модерация за 2020 год в цифрах

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, статистика

Наш подход к модерации сайтов — это ключевая особенность Stack Exchange:

> Мы проектируем движок сайтов сети так, чтобы все сообщества были максимально саморегулируемы. Это необходимо, чтобы объединить небольшой вклад каждого из тысяч обычных участников сообщества в единое целое.
> -- [Теория модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/6)

Хотя на сайте есть [модераторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), огромное количество *модерации содержимого* делается обычными участниками, которые используют заработанные на сайте привилегии. Так небольшой вклад в модерацию каждого в итоговой сумме огромен.

Недавно завершился календарный год. Давайте посмотрим, как выглядит модерация в цифрах за этот период.

| Действие | Модераторы | Сообщество¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Участников заблокировано² | 46 | 6 |
| Учетных записей уничтожено | 16 | 0 |
| Учетных записей удалено | 14 | 0 |
| Связь с участником | 194 | 0 |
| Отмененные блокировки | 1 | 0 |
| Проверка: предложенные правки³ | 86 | 29707 |
| Проверка: голоса за переоткрытие³ | 28 | 17225 |
| Проверка: сообщения низкого качества³ | 65 | 57792 |
| Проверка: запоздалые ответы³ | 0 | 5064 |
| Проверка: первые сообщения³ | 89 | 38083 |
| Проверка: очередь на закрытие³ | 211 | 38287 |
| Объединено меток | 5 | 0 |
| Предложено синонимов меток | 6 | 6 |
| Создано синонимов меток | 10 | 0 |
| Переписано версий | 27 | 0 |
| Снято защит с вопросов | 0 | 2 |
| Переоткрыто вопросов | 70 | 139 |
| Защищено вопросов | 3 | 135 |
| Перенесено вопросов | 7 | 15 |
| Объединено вопросов | 126 | 0 |
| Вопросов отмечено тревогой⁴ | 35 | 14553 |
| Закрыто вопросов | 804 | 10201 |
| Обработано тревог в вопросах⁴ | 2118 | 12624 |
| Сообщений разблокировано | 12 | 6 |
| Сообщений восстановлено | 94 | 1749 |
| Сообщений заблокировано | 86 | 101 |
| Сообщений удалено⁵ | 3012 | 36567 |
| Сообщений поднято | 0 | 8542 |
| Связь с командой управляющих | 3 | 0 |
| Комментариев восстановлено | 120 | 0 |
| Комментариев отмечено тревогой | 432 | 6202 |
| Комментариев удалено⁶ | 10586 | 29336 |
| Обработано тревог в комментариях | 4300 | 2331 |
| Отменено конкурсов | 3 | 0 |
| Отмечено тревогой ответов | 35 | 10449 |
| Обработано тревог в ответах | 7715 | 2763 |
| Комментариев преобразовано в чат | 266 | 0 |

#### Пояснения сносок

¹ Под «сообществом» здесь подразумеваются все [участники Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users) *за исключением* [тех, у кого рядом с именем отображается ромб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) и [Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² Система блокирует участника в трех случаях: когда заново создается ранее заблокированная учетная запись, когда новая учетная запись ранее была уничтожена за спам или оскорбления, а также когда участник блокируется на всех сайтах сети разом.

³ Подсчитываются все выполненные проверки (без пропущенных), то если для  предложенной правки необходимо 2 проверки, каждая будет включена.

⁴ Включает тревоги на закрытие (но *не включает* голоса за закрытие и переоткрытие).

⁵ Не включает большое количество автоматических удалений как реакцию на новые действия.

⁶ Включает комментарии удаленные авторами.

#### Дополнительно

- Хотите узнать как меняются данные со временем? Обратите внимание на данные за прошлый год: [Модерация за 2019 год в цифрах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9952/).
- Вы также можете посмотреть [на аналогичный отчёт для других сайтов сети](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22).

---

Огромная благодарность [@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) за SQL–запросы.

Comment: _Учетных записей удалено_ 0 - а самоудаления попали в модераторскую колонку? Или вообще не посчитались?

Comment: @Qwertiy Перепроверил. Запрос выдает «0 удаленных записей».

Comment: Коллеги, я подумываю написать небольшой пост-ответ, в котором бы хотел прокомментировать опубликованные цифры, исходя из собственного опыта модерирования: мне кажется, что подобный пост покажет, как читать подобные отчёты, а также поможет снять некоторые из типовых страхов участников сообщества. С кем мне стоит связаться, чтобы получить подтверждение, что публикуемые вещи не содержат сенситивной информации, нарушающей модераторское соглашение? Вероятно, достаточно написать Николаю в почту предварительный текст?

Comment: @AK Буду рад вам помочь! :)

Comment: @AK, ты уже не модератор, так что вся информация, к которой сейчас у тебя есть доступ, точно может использоваться. Или ты что-то другое хочешь опубликовать?

Comment: _Комментариев преобразовано в чат_ 266 - я правильно понимаю, что имеется в виду 266 случаев переноса, а не 266 комментариев?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я не сохранял никакую информацию типа скриншотов которые постил в мод.чате, но планирую поделиться воспоминаниями, поэтому вполне вероятно что какие-то вещи не стоит публиковать -- поэтому может перестраховка и лишняя, но поскольку я и дальше активный участник сообщества, то не хочу лишних конфликтных ситуаций.

Answer (score 6):

Не первый год читаю подобные отчёты, считая, что подобные отчёты делают более прозрачными действия модераторов и хотел бы немного прокомментировать исходя из своего опыта модерирования в 2019 - 2020 годах.

В первую очередь [снова](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9952/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0-2019-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%85#comment41490_9952) хочу отметить, что публикуемые из года в год цифры имеют примерно один и тот же порядок цифр, без резких скачков — поэтому вполне возможно аккуратно экстраполировать выводы прошлых лет на последнующие публикации.

Итак, по самому отчёту.

Первая строка - общее количество блокировок участников модераторами: 46 в 2020 году, примерно столько же в 2019 году. Это собственно то самое количество банов, оно по-прежнему держится на стабильно низком уровне, ни о каких массовых репрессиях и произволе речь не идёт.

Очень многих участников интересуют вопросы вида "а как часто банятся высокореповые участники?", попробую не раскрывая деталей по персональным данным пояснить этот момент.

Когда-то давно модератор @PashaPash говорил о том, что чаще всего баны (если не брать в расчёт откровенных новичков) ловят участники в момент набора 2-3 тысяч баллов репутации и я и ранее был согласен с ним из роли участника и более поздние наблюдения подтвердили эту картину.

Так что среди этих 46 участников думаю вряд ли будет более трети участников, которые набрали сколь существенную репутацию, в основном это новички. Если у модератора есть сомнения в том, стоит ли блокировать — он советуется с коллегами, очень многие случаи до блокировки не доходят именно на этой стадии: голоса разошлись и итоговое решение сделано в пользу участника.

Вторая строка — количество уничтоженных записей, их тоже немного. Тут могу чётко сказать, кто попадает в эту категорию: это спам-аккаунты, однодневки, грубо и бессовестно нарушающие правила сайта. Подобные участники никогда не обращались с жалобами на действия модераторов и я сомневаюсь, что когда-то будут прецеденты.

Возможно, из-за незнания как обстоит дело можно раздуть какие-то страшные истории о том, как какому-нибудь участнику, потратившему годы на создание контента обнуляют все его результаты и лишают постов, авторства. Ну, я вряд ли уже поверю в подобные городские легенды.

Также могу сказать, что подобные действия по уничтожению учёток подробно логируются в момент уничтожения и выводятся модератору, который проводит эту операцию — и потому выступают лишним напоминанием о персональной ответственности. Не знаю, насколько возможно восстановление подобных учёток (не удивлюсь, если это возможно), но в эту строку попадает такой откровенный хлам, что подобное вряд ли когда-то понадобится.

Удалённые учётные записи. Здесь практически то же самое, что и в предыдущем пункте: действия логируются, удаление похоже более "мягкое" (мне кажется, что должен быть какой-то инструмент undelete, но у ромбов его не видел). Сюда мы в своё время отправляли учётки в которых всё же могли быть (теоретические!!) сомнения, что эти записи придётся восстанавливать.

Подобных случаев также немного.

Отмененные блокировки. Говорят, что на основании цифр "количество отменённых приговоров" можно делать выводы о карательности/гуманности пенициарной системы. Оговаривая ограниченность подобных аналогий (so - не государство, многие участникина мете обсуждали насколько неверными могут быть подобные аналогии) могу сказать, что отмены блокировок возможны и *бывают*: если кто-то пессимистично считает, что бан — это что-то такое что никак не отменить, не оспорить то такие случаи бывают на практике, не только в теории.

Я недавно [упоминал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11255/213987) случай по одной из блокировок когда ошибся при назначении бана и отменял его, но не помню точно было это в 2019 году или в 2020. Мне кажется, что все три подобных случая — это истории когда ошибка была замечена сразу: либо модераторами, либо самим участником опротестована в мод. переписке, быстро исправлена и на публике не пришлось ни участнику краснеть, ни мод.составу получать упрёки.

Далее я пропущу несколько строк и прокомментирую сразу три строки: "Объединено меток", "Предложено синонимов меток" и "Создано синонимов меток". Надо сказать, что работа по упорядочиванию меток выстроена на stackoverflow не самым удобным образом — поэтому ей никто особо не занимается, а жаль. Для утверждения нужны несколько голосов (теоретически, участники с большой репутацией по метке могут это делать и сами, но речь идёт как правило о новых метках, по которой ни у кого нет должной репутации), нет выделенных очередей — поэтому я просто рекомендую сразу обращаться за помощью к модераторам в случаях когда всё очевидно, либо (создав тему на мете) порой смотреть статус.

Прямо говоря, я помню что за всё время модерирования я только один раз добрался до основательной расчистки меток, обычно просто не до неё. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

В части "переписывания версий" я год от года вижу резкий рост и это хорошо. Операция не самая простая технически, приходится два модератора онлайн быть, чтобы подтвердить все действия а в целом речь идёт о том, что из истории постов выпиливаются пароли к сервисам, БД и личным кабинетам. Я не видел, чтобы данные инструменты были использованы для сокрытия информации и ни разу не видел, чтобы они когда-либо применялись на мете к удалённым постам. Если есть 10к — читайте, всё как есть оставлено.

Разумеется, модераторы могут удалять комментарии, но про себя могу сказать следующее: Андрей и я в своё время приняли за правило, что мы не удаляем комментарии на мете в которых критикуются модераторы (а порой и нам доставалось) — чтобы не быть в положении людей, которых обвиняют в затыкании ртов собеседников, поэтому думаю что таких случаев было немного (когда прям совсем оскорбления) и никто скринами с пруфами тыкать не будет.

Интересный пункт "Связь с командой управляющих". Этих случаев по-прежнему к сожеланию мало, как-то сложилась традиция сразу предавать случаи огласки на мете, не исчерпав возможные варианты разрешения конфликта. Не знаю, насколько моё личное мнение совпадает с мнением других участников, но как по мне: участнику лучше сначала попробовать связаться с модераторами, если там не получится решить вопрос то использовать возможности по связи с командой управляющих и только потом идти на мету.

Вообще, мне сложно точно сказать, с какими вопросами обращаются к команде. Вполне возможно, что это какие-то вопросы по части использования материалов (лицензирование), либо вопросы по части внесения изменений в движок... Один случай, вероятно это был 2019 год я думаю, что знаю о чём был: это точно была жалоба на модератора и была официальная проверка действий, инспекцией с большого stackoverflow (вероятно, после моникагейт компания стала более ответственно подходить к процедурам по модерированию — на мой взгляд это можно только приветствовать).

Почему я хотел бы рассказать об этом случае? Дело в том, что просто участники не видят этой стороны и возможно у кого-то из участников складывается впечатление, что ничего не делается, что ничего не поменять и всё бессмыссленно. Не знаю, вырежут ли этот фрагмент при согласовании материала, но хочу чтобы и тот участник, который подал жалобу на модератора знал, что его заявка не была оставлена без рассмотрения и другие тоже понимали, что ящик для связи с командой — это не /dev/null в который бессмысленно писать.

Отменённые конкурсы. Мне сразу пришло в голову, что это речь о новогодних и нетематических конкурсах, про которые сейчас идёт горячее обсуждение на мете, но эта статистика будет видна только через год, а пока видимо речь о рядовых случаях, когда модераторы по запросу организатора конкурса отменяли его (возврат репутации, корректировка).

В остальном же видно, что действия модераторов в основном — капля в море среди действий, выполняемых самими участниками и сайт действительно во многом управляется самими участниками: тревоги, очереди проверок, голоса за закрытие, правки — всё это во многом мы сами своими руками делаем сайт чище и лучше.

Comment: Мне кажется, под связью с командой управляющих имеется в виду пункт в модераторском разделе по участнику, а не письма участников.

Comment: @Qwertiy Гм, судя по тому, что участники не связывались с управляющими (ноль в отчётах два года подряд) возможно, что в sql запросах оцениваются только "связь с командой" только через веб-форму, а не через почту. В общем, сами запросы Шога не видел, но твоя гипотеза выглядит более правдоподобной, чем то, что я писал в посте.