# Модерация за 2021 год в цифрах

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, статистика

Когда мы говорим пока прошлому году и приветствуем новый, у нас есть [традиция выкладывать статистику за минувший год](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

Как большинство из вас знает, сайты Stack Exchange модерируются иначе, чем другие сайты в интернете:

> Мы сконструировали движок Stack Exchange, так что бы преобладало саморегулирование, которое распределяет все усилия по модерации системы на мельчайшие части, с которыми помогают обычные посетители.
> -- [Теория модерации](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Это, тем не менее, не отменяет необходимости в [модераторах](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), но означает что большая часть модераторской работы выполняется обычными людьми. Каждая частичка времени и труда вы вносите в сайт, даёт вам доступ к большим привилегиям, которые вы можете использовать в этой помощи, и всё это создаёт накопительный эффект в этих различиях.

So as we say goodbye to 2021, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZntT.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Stack Overflow на русском over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 67 | 11 |
| Users destroyed³ | 42 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 57 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 97 | 0 |
| User suspensions lifted early | 1 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 22 | 23986 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 4 | 17377 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 54 | 44688 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 0 | 3561 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue | 0 | 16150 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 6 | 22611 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue | 0 | 7593 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 17 | 36440 |
| Tags merged | 5 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 2 | 10 |
| Tag synonyms created | 5 | 2 |
| Revisions redacted | 7 | 0 |
| Questions unprotected | 0 | 1 |
| Questions reopened | 91 | 185 |
| Questions protected | 0 | 274 |
| Questions migrated | 1 | 7 |
| Questions merged | 3 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 42 | 9799 |
| Questions closed | 854 | 12232 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 1417 | 8335 |
| Posts unlocked | 4 | 8 |
| Posts undeleted | 74 | 1457 |
| Posts locked | 12 | 212 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 1560 | 40048 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 8207 |
| Comments undeleted | 61 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 58 | 2405 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 8088 | 22421 |
| Comment flags handled | 1558 | 909 |
| Bounties canceled | 3 | 1 |
| Answers flagged | 64 | 8131 |
| Answer flags handled | 4434 | 3769 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 252 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [Модерация за 2020 год в цифрах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11288/181239)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222021%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374784/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2022! ^_^