# Важное - это не конкурс

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, мета, конкурс

Пост [Модерация за 2021 год в цифрах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11876/178988) отображается

| на правой панели меты | на правой панели сайта |
| --- | --- |
| в секции | как и должен в секции |
| ***Конкурсные*** | ***Важное на Мете*** |
| [image: скриншот с меты] | [image: скриншот с сайта] |

Учитывая то, что на нашей мете (да и на любой другой кроме главной) вообще не бывает конкурсных вопросов, тут какая-то ошибка. Только не знаю, в переводе или в логике сайта.

У вопроса есть метка [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Поправлено.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11323)

Будет в ближайших сборках. Текущая rev 2022.2.7.41389