# Какое правило SO нарушил данный вопрос?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, модераторский-произвол

Какое правило SO нарушил [данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1235905) вопрос? Он [был удалён](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1235905/timeline#history_710a417b-f60d-4dbb-bbab-95235bbdde71) модератором без пояснения.

[image: Скриншот удалённого вопроса]

<sub>**jetbrains-reset-Сброс-настроек-для-триал-версии-до-30-дней**</sub>

Comment: Никакое. [Отношение сообщества к вопросам, затрагивающим этику, правонарушения и интересы третьих лиц](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868)

Comment: На enSO есть вот такой [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51570570/3240681), например. Никто не удаляет.

Comment: Там даже сам вопрос и ответ сформулированы иначе: не как сломать, а как проверить - и даны все соответствующие дисклеймеры.

Comment: @andreymal как тогда восстановить вопрос?

Comment: @AK я не говорю про взлом. При чём тут взлом?

Comment: Восстановить могут только модераторы, т.к. удалено модератором.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ как призвать модераторов?

Comment: @hedgehogues как обычно: тревога - требуется вмешательство модератора

Comment: @αλεχολυτ только это не помогает. Призывал уже

Comment: @Sevastopol если правите вопрос, пожалуйста, уточняйте причину. На текущий момент выглядит модераторским произволом.

Comment: @hedgehogues, при быстрой правке меток нет такой технической возможности (уточнять причину правки)

Comment: А вообще, *возможно*, в лицензионном соглашении прописан какой-нибудь запрет на реверс-инжиниринг или что-нибудь такое, что запрещает в том числе и сабж. Тогда теоретически JetBrains может выписать люлей и автору, и сайту — но мне лень вычитывать тексты лицензий, чтобы выяснить, насколько это может быть правдой

Comment: @Sevastopol' поэтому я избегаю использования быстрой правки меток

Comment: Уважаемый Barmaley и другие закрывающие, на вопрос **очевидно можно дать объективный ответ**, потому что модератор, совершивший объективный факт удаления вопроса, объективно может написать своё пояснение, почему он его удалил. Переоткрыть.

Answer (score 6):

## Объективно

Вопрос очевидно является [онтопиком](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd) (удаляется вот таким образом только откровенный оффтопик, просто там "невозможно дать объективно верный ответ" — нет) , не содержит ни спама, ни оскорблений ⇒ удалить его точно нельзя. Его нельзя даже закрыть т.к. опять же таки это онтопик. Те, кому такие вопросы не нравятся — могут минусовать. И все.

Таким образом это похоже на... [модераторский-произвол](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb)... Хотя...

## Субъективно

Я считаю такие вопросы интересными, полезными и отношусь к ним положительно. Я не разбирают в законах, но я думаю, что если этот вопрос не подбивает никого ничего нарушать, а только говорит как — то все окей (например в учебных целях очень интересно). Я бы проголосовал за вопрос и ответ (если б он мне попался).

## Что можно улучшить

На law.SE есть интересная [полиси](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/222/34767).

> #### Closing for this reason In general, questions that ask for legal advice have the following characteristics:
>
> - They use pronouns that indicate a personal relationship "My mother was involved in an accident around the corner from my house..."
> - They contain highly emotive language
> - They explicitly ask "What should I do?" or something similar in the question
> - The only answer that you could safely give is "You should engage the services of a lawyer/attorney"
>
> **Important**: The presence of these indicators is not absolute proof that the question specifically asks for legal advice, but multiple
> factors are strong evidence that it does.
>
> Some questions might have the following characteristics, which
> indicates that they may not ask for legal advice:
>
> - They are explicitly phrased hypothetically: "Suppose I'm in a situation where..."
> - They use impersonal language and placeholder parties: "If person A does this to B..."
> - They ask for general information: "What legal recourse does B have?"
>
> **Again**: The presence of these characteristics is not absolute proof that the question is general and does not ask for legal advice, but
> multiple factors are strong evidence that it does not.

Все эти сложности нужны, чтобы не было проблем с законом — ни у автора вопроса, ни у автора/-ов ответа/-ов. Ваш вопрос не (совсем) подпадает под эти правила. В нем конкретно сказано, что вы хотите сбросить триал.

## Что стоит предпринять?

Переформулировать вопрос по [этим](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice) правилам и попросить модераторов восстановить.

> Какое правило SO нарушил данный вопрос?

Никакое, но правила ruSO слегка отличаются, так что вероятно модератор посчитал, что раз здесь допустимы вопросы связаные с законами и проч., то они должны соответствовать тем правилам.

## UPD

Вопрос [восстановлен](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56912456). Спасибо!

Comment: а причем тут правила про legal advice? Автор вообще ни о чем не спрашивает, он создал вопрос только для того, чтобы выложить инструкцию по сбросу триального периода у платной программы. Это как раз то, что гарантированно создаст "проблемы с законом", в том числе и для всего сайта.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Правила по legal advice хорошо подходят и для этого случая ИМХО. То, что сделал автор не создаст гарантировано проблем с законом (хотя может), это зависит от цели. Например, он сбросил этот триал (и думаеет: "во, круто я могу"), а дальше покупает IDE — нарушений нет. Ну а сайту — не знаю, как я сказал я не разбираюсь в законах.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight какой «закон» запрещает публиковать инструкции?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не забывайте, что имена авторов для QA не важны(!). Важны только сам вопрос, и ответ, их содержание и, отчасти, форма.